# PHP simpleXML how to save the file in a formatted way?

Tags: php, formatting, simplexml

I'm trying add some data to an existing XML file using PHP's SimpleXML. The problem is it adds all the data in a single line:

```
<name>blah</name><class>blah</class><area>blah</area> ...
```

And so on. All in a single line. How to introduce line breaks?

How do I make it like this?

```
<name>blah</name>
<class>blah</class>
<area>blah</area>
```

I am using `asXML()` function.

Thanks.

Comment: There's also the PEAR [XML_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Beautifier) package.

Comment: I know this is quite old question and you must have found solution. May be useful for others, have a look at it https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml

Answer (score 155):

You could use the [DOMDocument class](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to reformat your code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($simpleXml->asXML());
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: So it is not possible with SimpleXML?

Comment: @xcy7e No, I don’t think so.

Comment: When I tried to format content that I was appending to a file, it worked only if I specified preserveWhiteSpace and formatOutput before loading the existing content.

Answer (score 32):

Gumbo's solution does the trick. You can do work with simpleXml above and then add this at the end to echo and/or save it with formatting.

Code below echos it and saves it to a file (see comments in code and remove whatever you don't want):

```
//Format XML to save indented tree rather than one line
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($simpleXml->asXML());
//Echo XML - remove this and following line if echo not desired
echo $dom->saveXML();
//Save XML to file - remove this and following line if save not desired
$dom->save('fileName.xml');
```

Answer (score 19):

Use [`dom_import_simplexml`](http://www.php.net/function.dom_import_simplexml) to convert to a DomElement. Then use its capacity to format output.

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($simple_xml)->ownerDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: doesn't work. The function returns a DOMElement, not a DOMDocument

Comment: Seems `documentElement` should be `ownerDocument`. Not sure if the api changed or this is just a typo. I've corrected it now.

Comment: please note that this still doesn't work as the preserveWhiteSpace and formatOutput should be set _before_ importing the document to have any effect :)

Comment: Interesting - right you are. Looks like Gumbo's answer will work though.

Answer (score 2):

As [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) and [Witman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218120/witman) answered; loading and saving an XML document from an existing file (we're a lot of newbies around here) with [DOMDocument::load](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) and [DOMDocument::save](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php).

```
<?php
$xmlFile = 'filename.xml';
if( !file_exists($xmlFile) ) die('Missing file: ' . $xmlFile);
else
{
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $dom->formatOutput = true;
  $dl = @$dom->load($xmlFile); // remove error control operator (@) to print any error message generated while loading.
  if ( !$dl ) die('Error while parsing the document: ' . $xmlFile);
  echo $dom->save($xmlFile);
}
?>
```