# Adding linebreaks to XML generated by a PHP script

Tags: php, xml

I've generated an XML file via PHP. However, the XML has been generated all on one line, with no linebreaks or indentation.

How can I make it so that each link in the XML file appears on a separate line? Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement('<links></links>');
$xml->addChild('dvd');

foreach ($articleList as $art) {
    $value = htmlentities($art->getAttribute('href'));
    $xml->addChild('alink', $value);
}

$xml->asXML('/simplexml_create.xml');
```

Comment: Try opening your XML file in a browser like Chrome or Firefox. Usually they have some built-in XML node explorer that will make things a bit prettier to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beautify xml file is a bad idea, because in 1 line it's takes less disk space. 
use xml formatting only for debugging purposes, this tool helps you - http://xmlbeautifier.com/default.aspx 
see this question: [Format output of $SimpleXML->asXML();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191167/format-output-of-simplexml-asxml) 
in Opera browser 1 line xml displays with formatting

Comment: Ok i understand your point. But I still want it more readable while i develop the xml file as it will become a lot more complicated and I'll need to beable to quickly reference how its looking.