# How to convert array to xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get an xml file from a foreach loop from an array but im getting only 1 row in the xml file.

Is there another way to convert the array data to xml file in this format?

PHP:

```
$item = array();
        $item[] = array('CityId'    => $row['city_id'],
                        'StateId'   => $row['state_id'],
                        'CityName'  => $row['city_name']
                        );

        $break = "<br />";
        $quote = '"';
        $xml = "<data>"."\n";
        foreach($item as $_item) {

            echo $xml .= "<city CityId=$quote" . $_item['CityId'] . "$quote StateId=$quote" . $_item['StateId'] . "$quote CityName=$quote" . $_item['CityName'] . "$quote />\n";

        }
        $xml .= "</data>";
        $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
        echo $output = $sxml->asXML("data.xml");
```

Output data.xml:

```
<data>
<city CityId="1" StateId="217" CityName="New York" />
<city CityId="2" StateId="218" CityName="New Jersey" />
</data>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml ? It should give you something to start with.

Comment: Yes, i read that post, the format is different.

Comment: My issue is that im getting only 1 row instead 10, 100, or how many are in the array.

Comment: A side note, since you're already using SimpleXML, you can use it all the way trough (`$city=$xml->addChild("city");$city->addAttribute("CityId","1");...`), instead of caching a whole string and then convert it to SimpleXML.

Comment: I suppose `$row` is coming fram a database? Looks like your not looping trough the results from your query. Add `print_r($item,true)` before your foreach and see how many items the array has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data :

```
 $cities = array(
        array(
            'cityId' => 1,
            'stateId' => 217,
            'cityName' => 'New York'
        ),
        array(
            'cityId' => 2,
            'stateId' => 0,
            'cityName' => 'Paris'
        ),
    );
```

This :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');
foreach ($cities as $key => $city)
{
    $xml->city[$key]['cityId'] = $city['cityId'];
    $xml->city[$key]['stateId'] = $city['stateId'];
    $xml->city[$key]['cityName'] = $city['cityName'];
}
```

OR (better)  :

```
xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');
foreach ($cities as $cityData)
{
    $city = $xml->addChild('city');
    $city->addAttribute('cityId', $cityData['cityId']);
    $city->addAttribute('stateId', $cityData['stateId']);
    $city->addAttribute('cityName', $cityData['cityName']);
}
```

Will output :

```
<data>
    <city cityId="1" stateId="217" cityName="New York" />
    <city cityId="2" stateId="0" cityName="Paris" />
</data>
```

Comment: Hello Brice, this is what i need, can you please tell me how can i format the outpup xml? i mean the output is all inline. Thx a lot

Comment: Quoted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191167/format-output-of-simplexml-asxml : You can use `dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument`. Then set `$dom->formatOutput = true` and you can get the result via `$dom->saveXML()`

Answer (score 0):

have a look here. i have been using this function to convert array to xml. hope it will help you.

http://vantulder.net/old-articles/array-to-xml

Comment: Hi @Joseph, is not the right format there. Thanks a lot.