# PHP, write well formatted xml document

Tags: php

I'm writing to an xml file using PHP function SimpleXMLElement, the xml writes succesfully but is not well formatted, all data is in one line. i would like it to be something like these

```
<Shoe>
   <brand>Nike</brand>
   <type>Lebron</type>
   <Release Date>2015/02/11</Release Date>
</Shoe>
```

here is my code, thanks in adavnce.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydoc></mydoc>');
$xml->addAttribute('version', '1.0');
$xml->addChild('datetime', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$person = $xml->addChild('Shoe');
$person->addChild('brand', 'Nike');
$person->addChild('type', 'Jordan');
$person->addChild('Release Date', '2014/05/21');

$person = $xml->addChild('Shoe');
$person->addChild('brand', 'Adidas');
$person->addChild('type', 'Stan Smith');
$person->addChild('Release Date', '2014/0/03');

$xml->saveXML("shoeOrder.xml");
```

Comment: Also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191167/format-output-of-simplexml-asxml)

Comment: Note that "well formed" (I know, not *formatted*) is a term with its own meaning in XML, and this XML is certainly *well formed* and also well formatted as far as XML is concerned. You simply want to make it more readable to humans.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the question you refered to is a duplicate already, so that doesn't really help.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Both answers of the second reference can be found in the First one.

Comment: @Irdrah, "doesn't really help", n answer from you would help..give me a link to the duplicate.

Comment: Why should I provide you another link to the original question, when many others have already given you multiple. It's not my fault that you lack the desire to take any action whatsoever.

Comment: @Irdrah.. Thanx fr ur enthusiasm bt i solved this a long tym ago, mayb find somethnign else to do.