# How to create an xml feed from woocommerce for other cms platforms?

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system, feed

I have an b2b eshop based on woocommerce. I want to provide my customers an xml feed so they can import products from my store into their stores that are based not only on woocommerce but on other cms platform too. Is there any way to do that? I talked to creators of some very known plugins(WP Allimport/Export) and they say that is very difficult and complex. 
What I want to export into xml is the product informations like title, category, attributes, price, images, description, stock... Also I want this xml file to update every 5 minutes. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To create an XML from your Woocommerce products, you could use the woocommerce rest api to serve a jSON file of your products.

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#introduction

Then create a cron job every 5 minutes, for a script to convert your jSON to XML file.

[How do I Convert jSON to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964136/how-do-i-convert-json-to-xml/26964222)