# How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?

Tags: php, dom, innerhtml

What function do you use to get innerHTML of a given DOMNode in the PHP DOM implementation? Can someone give reliable solution?

Of course outerHTML will do too.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

[Compare](https://www.diffchecker.com/Ay08mF8z) this updated variant with [PHP Manual User Note #89718](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#89718):

```
<?php 
function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children  = $element->childNodes;

    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }

    return $innerHTML; 
} 
?>
```

Example:

```
<?php 
$dom= new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput       = true;
$dom->load($html_string); 

$domTables = $dom->getElementsByTagName("table"); 

// Iterate over DOMNodeList (Implements Traversable)
foreach ($domTables as $table) 
{ 
    echo DOMinnerHTML($table); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Shouldn't $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; be before document load?

Comment: @JohnM2: [Yes it should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way).

Comment: Additional notes: Since PHP 5.3.6 you can spare the temporary `DOMDocument`. Also one might want to replace the `trim` with an `ltrim` (or even remove it completely) to preserve a bit of the whitespace like line-breaks.

Comment: A function like this should be added to the DomDocument class.

Comment: I had to change the function declaration to expect a `DOMElement` instead of a `DOMNode` as I was passing the return from `DOMDocument::getElementById()`. Just in case it trips someone else up.

Comment: Why do you loop through all the children? Couldn't you just `saveHTML()` on the `$table`? Look: [PHP outerHTML S/O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/how-to-return-outer-html-of-domdocument)

Comment: This doesn't work. The error is "DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given"

Comment: Notice: this does not return original, but little modified HTML, for example having `11<br>22<br/>33` you will not get exact version.

Answer (score 38):

Here is a version in a *functional programming* style:

```
function innerHTML($node) {
    return implode(array_map([$node->ownerDocument,"saveHTML"], 
                             iterator_to_array($node->childNodes)));
}
```

Answer (score 19):

To return the `html` of an element, you can use [C14N()](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$x = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($x->query('//table') as $table){
    echo $table->C14N();
}
```

Comment: C14N will attempt to convert the HTML to a valid XML. For example <br> will become <br></br>

Comment: It's a dirty way of dump the HTML of the element, without having to use saveHTML that will output html, head and body tags.

Comment: echo utf8_decode($table->C14N());

Answer (score 11):

A simplified version of Haim Evgi's answer:

```
<?php

function innerHTML(\DOMElement $element)
{
    $doc = $element->ownerDocument;

    $html = '';

    foreach ($element->childNodes as $node) {
        $html .= $doc->saveHTML($node);
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Example usage:

```
<?php

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<body><div id='foo'><p>This is <b>an <i>example</i></b> paragraph<br>\n\ncontaining newlines.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p></div></body>");

print innerHTML($doc->getElementById('foo'));

/*
<p>This is <b>an <i>example</i></b> paragraph<br>

containing newlines.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
*/
```

There's no need to set `preserveWhiteSpace` or `formatOutput`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to trincot's nice version with `array_map` and `implode` but this time with `array_reduce`:

```
return array_reduce(
   iterator_to_array($node->childNodes),
   function ($carry, \DOMNode $child) {
        return $carry.$child->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
   }
);
```

Still don't understand, why there's no `reduce()` method which accepts arrays and iterators alike.

Answer (score 3):

```
function setnodevalue($doc, $node, $newvalue){
  while($node->childNodes->length> 0){
    $node->removeChild($node->firstChild);
  }
  $fragment= $doc->createDocumentFragment();
  $fragment->preserveWhiteSpace= false;
  if(!empty($newvalue)){
    $fragment->appendXML(trim($newvalue));
    $nod= $doc->importNode($fragment, true);
    $node->appendChild($nod);
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to pass the document to the function, you can use `$node->ownerDocument`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach based on [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#105815) by Drupella on php.net, that worked well for my project. It defines the `innerHTML()` by creating a new `DOMDocument`, importing and appending to it the target node, instead of explicitly iterating over child nodes.

### InnerHTML

Let's define this helper function:

```
function innerHTML( \DOMNode $n, $include_target_tag = true ) {
  $doc = new \DOMDocument();
  $doc->appendChild( $doc->importNode( $n, true ) );
  $html = trim( $doc->saveHTML() );
  if ( $include_target_tag ) {
      return $html;
  }
  return preg_replace( '@^<' . $n->nodeName .'[^>]*>|</'. $n->nodeName .'>$@', '', $html );
}
```

where we can include/exclude the outer target tag through the second input argument.

### Usage Example

Here we extract the inner HTML for a target tag given by the "first" id attribute:

```
$html = '<div id="first"><h1>Hello</h1></div><div id="second"><p>World!</p></div>';
$doc  = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html );
$node = $doc->getElementById( 'first' );

if ( $node instanceof \DOMNode ) {

    echo innerHTML( $node, true );
    // Output: <div id="first"><h1>Hello</h1></div>    

    echo innerHTML( $node, false );
    // Output: <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

Live example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2714ea116aad9957c3c437d46134a1688e9133b8

Answer (score 2):

Old query, but there is a built-in method to do that. Just pass the target node to `DomDocument->saveHtml()`.

Full example:

```
$html = '<div><p>ciao questa è una <b>prova</b>.</p></div>';
$dom = new DomDocument($html);
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query('.//div/*'); // with * you get inner html without surrounding div tag; without * you get inner html with surrounding div tag
$innerHtml = $dom->saveHtml($node);
var_dump($innerHtml);
```

Output: `<p>ciao questa è una <b>prova</b>.</p>`

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, object given

Answer (score 1):

For people who want to get the HTML from XPath query, here is my version:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $my_dom_object );

$DOMNodeList = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "some_custom_class_in_html")]');

if( $DOMNodeList->count() > 0 ) {
    $page_html = $my_dom_object->saveHTML( $DOMNodeList->item(0) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML using `C14N()` and xpath query:

```php
$node->C14N(
   true, // parse only xpath query nodes
   false, // without comments
   ["query" => ".//node()|.//*//@*"] // select all inner nodes & attributes
);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit (PHP 8)

`mb_convert_encoding` with `HTML-ENTITIES` is deprecated in PHP 8.

```php
function setInnerHTML($element, $content) {
    $DOMInnerHTML = new DOMDocument();
    $DOMInnerHTML->loadHTML(
        <<<HTML
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>
                $content
            </body>
        </html>
        HTML,
    );
    foreach (
        $DOMInnerHTML->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes
        as $contentNode
    ) {
        $contentNode = $element->ownerDocument->importNode($contentNode, true);
        $element->appendChild($contentNode);
    }
}
```

Including an HTML boilerplate is probably the best way to achieve clean, UTF-8 encoded text within the added DOM nodes. I've tried creating a drop-in replacement for `mb_convert_encoding` with `HTML-ENTITIES`, but I always ended up with mojibake.

### Original

After experimenting with some implementations I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778110/change-innerhtml-of-a-php-domelement), I engineered the perfect solution that you can use to set inner HTML:

```php
function setInnerHTML($element, $content) {
    $DOMInnerHTML = new DOMDocument();
    $DOMInnerHTML->loadHTML(
        mb_convert_encoding("<div>$content</div>", 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')
    );
    foreach (
        $DOMInnerHTML->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes
        as $contentNode
    ) {
        $contentNode = $element->ownerDocument->importNode($contentNode, true);
        $element->appendChild($contentNode);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Because of the `mb_convert_encoding` function, this also requires the `mbstring` extension. If you omit the call here, this might cause mojibake.
- This creates a `<div>` element to prevent creating an implicit `<p>` if there is no root element. This prevents problems when embedding into an element like `<title>`.
- To not create a `DocumentFragment`, this fetches a `DOMNodeList` of the nodes, iterates through it, and appends each node to the element.
- Ideally, setters should not return a value.

I created this to implement a basic templating system into a school project of mine.