# Regex match HTML tag NOT containing another tag

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I am writing a regex find/replace that will insert a `<span>` into every `<a href>` in a file where a `<span>` does not already exist. It will allow other tags to be in the `<a href>` like `<img>`, `<b>`, etc.

Currently I have this regex:
Find: `(<a[^>]+?style=".*?color:#(\w{6}).*?".*?>)(.+?)(<\/a>)`
Replace: `'$1<span style="color:#$2;">$3</span>$4'`

It works great except if i run it over the same file, it will insert a `<span>` inside of a `<span>` and it gets messy.

Target Example:

We want it to ignore this:
    `<a href="http://mywebiste.com/link1.html" target="_blank" style="color:#bfbcba; text-decoration:underline;"><span style="color:#bfbcba;">Howdy</span></a>`

But not this:
    `<a href="http://mywebiste.com/link1.html" target="_blank" style="color:#bfbcba; text-decoration:underline;">Howdy</a>`

Or this:
    `<a href="http://mywebiste.com/link1.html" target="_blank" style="color:#bfbcba; text-decoration:underline;"><img src="myimg.gif" />Howdy</a>`

--EDIT--

Using the PHP DOM library as suggested in the comments, this is what I have so far:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $spancount = $tag->getElementsByTagName("span")->length;
    if($spancount == 0){
        $element = $doc->createElement('span');
        $tag->appendChild($element);
    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();`
```

Currently it will detect if there is a span inside an anchor and if there is, it will append a span to the inside of the anchor, however, i have yet to figure out how to get the original contents of the anchor inside the span.

Comment: In what language? Could be Perl or PHP or Javascript?

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to match HTML.  Use an HTML Parser.

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse XML (HTML) is a bad idea. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: This answers your question perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/13365

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regex for this, it's not ideal for HTML.

Use a DOM library and `getElementsByTagName('a')` then iterate through each anchor and see if it contains a sub span element with `getElementsByTagName('span')`, using the `length` property. If it doesn't, `appendChild` or assign the `firstChild` of the anchor node to your new span created with `document.createElement('span')`.

**EDIT:** As for grabbing the inner html of the anchor, if there are lots of nodes inside, try using this:

```
<?php
function innerHTML($node){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));

  return $doc->saveHTML();
}

$html = innerHTML( $anchorRef );
```

This may also help you out: [Change innerHTML of a php DOMElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778110/change-innerhtml-of-a-php-domelement)

Comment: Full ack, regex and html = bad. Though I would probably use an html parser or even simplexml instead of javascript for the sake of ppl who use lynx.

Comment: Thanks for the DOM suggestions. I have started using the PHP DOM (for the first time!) and I am having a heck of a time sorting out how to take the contents of an element: `<a href="link.html"><b>my link</b></a>` in this case `<b>my link</b>` and then wrapping that in a span.  I've had no problem creating the new span element, and appending it, but getting the original contents inside the `<span>` has been stumping me.

Comment: Well, it would be much easier for me ( and others ) to help if you posted your attempt in your original answer.

Comment: One problem having with the above `innerHTML()` function is that it returns a string and when I set the set the `nodeValue` of the anchor to the returned string, the HTML is escaped like:  
`<a href="#"><u>Underlined Link</u><span style="color:#ffffff;">&lt;u&gt;Underlined Link&lt;/u&gt;
</span></a>`
The body of my `foreach` loop now looks like this:  
`   $element = $doc->createElement('span');
   $content = innerHTML($tag);
   $element->setAttribute('style','color:#ffffff;');
   $element->nodeValue = $content;
   $tag->nodeValue = ""; //clear node
   $tag->appendChild($element);`