# php DOMDocument element value can't be HTML

Tags: php, html, domdocument

This is the code related to the problem:

`$prep = "<select><option>Option 1</option><option selected>Option 1</option></select>"

 $td = $dom->createElement('td',$prep);`

Solution:

```
$f = $this->dom->createDocumentFragment();
$f->appendXML($prep);
```

BUT still a big problem. Any attributes without value ex: `selected`, `disabled` (which you can't write as  `selected="selected"`) the `createElement` doesn't allow you to do so.

How can use attributes without value, and not get 1000 erros like now: 
`Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML() [domdocumentfragment.appendxml]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Specification mandate value for attribute selected
Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML() [domdocumentfragment.appendxml]: Entity: line 2: parser error : chunk is not well balanced`

This happens when passing a `selected` attribute, or disabled.

Comment: What is your problem actually

Comment: So in some elements, like for example the value of the TD I send HTML syntax, and it is not interpreted in the saveHTML() when I echo everything, it shows up as `<strong>a@a.com</strong>` insted of just going bold or whatever. I got <select> that shows up as <select><option>name</option><option>nameofvalue</option></select>

Comment: Found this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778110/change-innerhtml-of-a-php-domelement]

Comment: @user2156913: How does your function look? What are you inputting? What are you getting as output? What are you **expecting** to get as output? Without *all* of these, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot resist correcting. In PHP's implementation of the DOMDocument model, strings are `also` objects (this allows you to easily select them rather than to rely on nodeValue, which makes life easier in most cases).

To insert a table row with text, do this:

```
$f = new DOMDocument();
$table = $f->createElement("table");
$f->appendChild($table);
$tbody = $f->createElement("tbody");
$table->appendChild($tbody);
$tr = $f->createElement("tr");
$tbody->appendChild($tr);
$td = $f->createElement("td");
$tr->appendChild($td);

// Magic happens here
$td->appendChild(new DOMText("this is my text"));
```

Empty attributes are conserved when inserted properly, by the way - but you're free to use selected="selected", it is still valid provided that its content is the lowercase version of its attribute name ( [What does it mean in HTML 5 when an attribute is a boolean attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute) ). If you'd still prefer to just flag it as boolean true, use:

```
$elem->setAttribute("selected","");
```

(I just ran the code + mode and got no errors whatsoever without the need to use shutop)

Comment: the was not what the problem is about.
sure, the magic works if it's text you are sending to the child(), but I am sending HTML string and it gets appended as text if you use your method. 

`$td->appendChild(new DOMText("this is my text"));` insted of this try this `$td->appendChild(new DOMText("<strong>this is my text</strong>"));` or any kind of append to the DOM of HTML formated syntax.

As for selected it does not work because of the appendXML witch reports missuse.

Comment: Every single item in DOMDocument's structure *is* an object. You can load them using `appendXML`, but you're risking the consequences: an attribute without a value is *not* valid XML, and DOMDocument will throw up if you do. This is why I went down the object-creation path. If you really want to bypass that, use `tidy` before appendXML.

Comment: OBJECT CREATION PATH using TEXT witch is not even necessary. You can use `$td->nodeValue =  "your text here";`

BUT inserting HTML syntax does not work

Comment: @user2156913: guess what? One is an alias of the other. Can you guess which one? As for HTML - I told you exactly the solution already: you either `appendXML` and provide **proper** XML, or you create the objects one by one. (Or you `tidy` `cleanRepair()` your input first)

Comment: guess what @sebastian ? Your solutions DOES NOT WORK ! I just tried it. As text yes, but that's easy, I was talking about html code. Maybe you should read again the problem.

Comment: I have said it three times already. I will say it a fourth time: if you want to inject HTML through an **XML** DOM traversal utility, I suggest you actually feed it **VALID** XML. `appendXML()` "<option selected='selected'>Test</option>" on a documentFragment goes through without a single error. I will say it a fourth time: you can create the objects one by one, or you can feed it valid XML. For all your other uses, there is text.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my self.
`$this->dom = new DOMDocument;`
all other code and what you build
`$tbody = $this->dom->createElement('tbody');`
`$td = $this->dom->createElement('td');`

To put a piece of html code in the TD you can't just paste it or set the value via ->nodeValue = ''. It will output as text, NOT as HTML.

`$prep = "<strong>lalala</strong>";` or any other html string 
// create fragment and append it
`@@$f = $this->dom->createDocumentFragment();
@@$f->appendXML($prep);`
`$td->appendChild($f);`

-- it WORKS! but be careful :: Any sort of empty attribute to a HTML tag like `<option selected>` or `<option disabled>` will cause errors and fail. 
Don't try to set attribute as `selected="selected"`. That will also fail due to the HTML/XML parser.

SO `createDocumentFragment()` works very well as long as you dont have empty value attributes like selected,disabled or other