# PHP str_ireplace does not remove content from DomDocument tags

Tags: php, html

I am trying to remove all content from the `td` tag having the `class` **attribute** by serving as `stripos` to check if the `td` indeed has the `class` **attribute** and from `str_ireplace` to replace this `navigation-only` **CSS content class** (`<td class="navigation-only"> ... </td>`) with empty double quotes as you can see in my Code below:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://website.ndd");

$getTableTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName("table");
$getTdTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName("td");
foreach ($getTableTags as $getTableTag) {
    if (stripos($getTableTag->getAttribute('class'), "infotec") !== false) {
        foreach ($getTdTags as $getTdTag) {
            if (stripos($getTdTag->getAttribute('class'), "navigation-only") !== false) {
                // var_dump($getTableTag);
                // $completeInfoxbox = $doc->saveHTML($getTableTag);
                $getInfoboxPatch1 = str_ireplace($getTdTag, "", $getTableTag);
                echo $doc->saveHTML($getInfoboxPatch1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a 100% blank Page yet I did an: `echo $doc->saveHTML($getInfoboxPatch1)`.

So, how can I correct my code so as to REMOVE all the `<td>` HTML tags having the `class` attribute whose content of this `class` attribute is `navigation-only`: `<td class=" navigation-only"> ... </td>` ???

Please help me please.

Comment: See answer for [Change innerHTML of a php DOMElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38815450/2743458)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$getInfoboxPatch1 = str_ireplace($getTdTag, "", $getTableTag);
// throws error: str_ireplace(): Argument #1 ($search) must be of type array|string, DOMElement given
```

[`str_ireplace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) takes strings or arrays as search and object parameters. You're passing [`PHP DOMElements`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

To change a PHP DOMDocument element you need to remove the existing element, create a new one, and append it to the old element's parent.

In this case you are removing a text node, creating a new text node, and appending the new text node to the TD tag:

```php
if (stripos($getTdTag->getAttribute('class'), "navigation-only") !== false) {

  // remove child nodes
  while ( $getTdTag->hasChildNodes() ) {
    $getTdTag->removeChild($getTdTag->firstChild);
  }

  // create empty text node
  $emptyTextNode = $doc->createTextNode("");

  // append to TD tag
  $getTdTag->appendChild($emptyTextNode);

  //show updated tag
  echo $doc->saveHTML($getTdTag);

}
```