# How to get Anchor text using DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

Say I have this html:

```
<a href="http://example.com">Test</a>
```

I parse it using `DOMDocument` with this code:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

And then I run this code:

```
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    //echo "<br> {$url->getAttribute('href')} , {$url->getAttribute('title')}";
    foreach ($url->attributes as $a)
    {
        echo "<br>$a->name is $a->value";
    }
    echo "<hr><br>";
}
```

When I do this, I only see 'href' as an attribute of the url, there's no way to get the 'anchor text' (in the above case 'Test'). How can I get the anchor text of the link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $attributes = $url->attributes;
    echo "<br>$url->nodeValue is $attributes->href";
}
```

Comment: i have a image tag as the anchor text of a link. if i use nodeValue it does not return anything. i am using find('a[href=url]') to get the matching anchor link. How can i get the image tag??

Comment: textContent does not return anything. it should return something like <img src='someurl.jpg' alt='something'/> but does not

Comment: innertext did the trick. it returns the image tag fine now. thanks dqhendricks

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DOMNode::$nodeValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue):

```
echo $url->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
here is two line code may it help some one

$html   =   file_get_html($link);
foreach($html->find("a") as $key=>$val)
{
  echo $val->src;
  echo '\n';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text "Test" is actually a DOM Text node so you can fetch the content by going through the children nodes of $url.

You can check this post for solution: [How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Comment: This is actually meant to obtain the innerHTML, you might want to use nodeValue if all you want is the text inside as @lonesomeday pointed out.