# How would one get the value/text of an anchor DOMElement?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Anchor text using DomDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629071/how-to-get-anchor-text-using-domdocument)
>   [Getting node's text in PHP DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399924/getting-nodes-text-in-php-dom)

I have a script that finds all the anchor tags of a certain class in a DOMDocument. I am looking to echo the text that is contained within the `<a>"....."</a>` tags.

Comment: The `nodeValue` property holds it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access DOMText node directly using XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom_document);
$node = $xpath->query('//a/text()')->item(0);
echo $node->textContent; // text
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use preg_match(). Here is an example:

```
$link = '<a href="http://www.coursesweb.net" title="www.CoursesWeb.net">www.CoursesWeb.net</a>';
if(preg_match('/\<a([^\>]*)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/i', $link, $mc)) {
  echo $mc[2];         // www.CoursesWeb.net
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.