# Preserve line breaks inside <p> tags using DOMXPath?

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I'm currently using PHP and `DOMXPath` to get the contents of all of the `<p>` elements of a web page:

```
<?php
...    
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$paragraphs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//p");

foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph){
echo $paragraph->textContent . "<br />";
}
```

My problem is that the string resulting from `textContent` does not respect `<br />` tags that exist within those `<p>` elements.  Instead it removes the line break and pushes words together that would normally be on separate lines.  For example:

Sample HTML:

```
<p>
Some happy talk goes here talking about our great product.<br />
We would love for you to buy it!
</p>

<p>
Random information and what not<br />
Isn't that cool?
</p>
```

Current Output from PHP above:

```
Some happy talk about our great product.We would love for you to buy it!

Random information and what notIsn't that cool?
```

I have tried `$paragraphs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("p");` as well and it gives me the same thing.

Is there a way to make DOMXPath/DOMDocument preserve the line breaks? I need to be able to separate each of the words within a paragraph, and the current output disallows that.

If there is an alternative method for retrieving the string within `<p>` elements while preserving `<br />` or `'\n'` that would also be great.

**EDIT**

---

Upon further investigation the HTML in question is actually a list of anchors separated by `<br>` tags but with no actual line breaks:

```
<p class="home_page_list"><a href="/home/personal-banking/checking/Category-Page-Classic-Checking/classic-checking.html">Classic Checking</a><br> <a href="/home/personal-banking/checking/Category-Page-Interest-Checking/interest-checking.html">Interest Checking</a><br> <a href="/home/personal-banking/checking/Category-Page-Interest-Checking/interest-premium-checking.html">Premium Checking</a><br> <a href="/home/personal-banking/Savings-Category-Page/Basic-Savings-Category-Page/basic-savings.html">Savings Plans</a><br> <a href="/home/personal-banking/Savings-Category-Page/Money-Market-Accounts-Category-Page/money-market-accounts.html">Money Market Accounts</a><br> <a href="/home/personal-banking/Savings-Category-Page/Certificates-of-Deposit-Category-Page/fixed-rate-CD.html">CDs</a><br> <a href="/home/personal-banking/Savings-Category-Page/Individual-Retirement-Account-Category-Page/individual-retirement-account.html">IRAs</a></p>
```

Turns out that this works properly with the original HTML given.

**UPDATE: Solved**

---

With the help of @ircmaxell's answer, and the comments left by @netcoder and @Gordon this has been solved, it's not very elegant but it will do for now.

Example:

```
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph){
    $p_text = new DOMDocument();
    $p_text->loadHTML(str_ireplace(array("<br>", "<br />"), "\r\n", DOMinnerHTML($paragraph)));
    //Do whatever, in this case get all of the words in an array.
    $words = explode(" ", str_ireplace(array(",", ".", "&", ":", "-", "\r\n"), " ", $p_text->textContent));
print_r($words);
}
```

This makes use of [DOMinnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument) (as suggested by @netcoder) to replace the instances of `<br>` with "\r\n" (as suggested by @ircmaxell), which can then be evaluated post `textContent.`

Obviously there's some room for improvement, but it has solved my current issue.

Thanks for the help everyone,

Ben

Comment: @Ben: You're sure? What PHP version? Works as expected on PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Note: To preserve inner tags (e.g.: `<br>`, `<span`, etc.), you have to use a recursive function to extract the element's "innerHTML".

Comment: @netcoder: pretty sure, although I won't say it's not possible I'm doing something wrong. Unfortunately our host is on PHP 5.2.12.

Comment: @Ben: Also works as expected on PHP 5.2.10. How are you outputting this? In a web browser? If so, what are you looking at, the formatted output or the page source?

Comment: @Ben `textContent` returns the text content of this node and its descendants, e.g. it concatenates the value of all the DOMText child nodes.

Comment: @netcoder: Yes, in a browser.  When you say expected, what do you mean?

Comment: @Gordon@netcoder: Thank you both, I think it may have to do with what Gordon mentioned. I'm afraid my example HTML was not precise enough. I'll edit for a better example.  The issue appears to be when each line in the `<p>` is an `<a>` separated by a `<br>`.

Comment: @Ben Happy to help. I still dont get what your actual problem is though.

Comment: @Ben: See [innerHTML in PHP's DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument).

Comment: @Gordon, When retrieving the `textContent` of a `<p>` tag that has multiple `<a>` tags separated in the source by a `<br>` but not a carriage return the last word of the first anchor gets smushed against the first word of the second anchor.  My problem is that I need to be able to separate them into separate words.

Comment: @Ben Ah, I see. Yes, you are looking for innerHTML then, which DOM does not implement. There is a number of possible solutions to it in the [comments to DOMElement though](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, what I would do is replace the line-breaks with literal linebreaks:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$brs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('br');
foreach ($brs as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($doc->createTextNode("\r\n"), $node);
}


$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$paragraphs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//p");

foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph){
    echo $paragraph->textContent . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the possibilities

```
echo simplexml_import_dom($paragraph)->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same situation, i use:

```
$document->loadHTML(str_replace('<br>', urlencode('<br>'), $string_or_file));
```

And i use urlencode() to change it back for display or inserting to database.