# How to get pieces of content separated with <br /> with the DOM

Tags: php, dom, line-breaks

There is:

```
<p class="ad">
Name: John Doe<br />
Phone: (123) 456-7890<br />
Address: 123 Main Street<br />
Msg: Hello World!
</p>
```

If I use:

```
$query = "//p[@class='ad']";
```

Returns content as a single string:

```
Name: John DoePhone: (123) 456-7890Address: 123 Main StreetMsg: Hello World!
```

How could I get the separate sections (separated by `<br />` (4 different strings)) with the DOM? Is it even possible? If not so, any other alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve line breaks inside <p> tags using DOMXPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739896/preserve-line-breaks-inside-p-tags-using-domxpath)