DOMNode->replaceChild() in PHP does not replace all relevant all relevant children, but only the first one
I am facing a similar situation to: Preserve line breaks inside <p> tags using DOMXPath?
I tried the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740264/2206865, which replaces <br> tags with literal line breaks, encapsulating into a function like so:
/* preserve all newlines by switching out <br>, which will be lost if you $node->textContent */
function newDOMDocumentBetter ($htmlstr) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($htmlstr, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

$brs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('br');
foreach ($brs as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($doc->createTextNode("\r\n"), $node);
}
    echo $doc->C14N();
    return $doc;
}

Somehow the above code does not replace the <br> tags correctly.
Before calling newDOMDocumentBetter ($htmlstr), $htmlstr is:
<code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&lt;?php<br />$first </span><span style="color: #007700">? </span><span style="color: #0000BB">$second </span><span style="color: #007700">: </span><span style="color: #0000BB">$third<br />?&gt;</span></span></code>

After replaceChild() is called, the echo statement returns:
<html><body><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&lt;?php&#xD;
</span><span style="color: #007700">? </span><span style="color: #0000BB"> </span><span style="color: #007700">: </span><span style="color: #0000BB"><br></br>?&gt;</span></span></code></body></html>

I can see that the first  tag has been replaced by a newline, but not the second tag. How do I make sure replaceChild() replaces all of the relevant children?

When you alter the node-tree using replaceChild() the references are also altered, so the foreach may terminate prematurely, since getElementsByTagName() returns an Iterator and so it is dynamic.
I suggest you to pin the nodes returned by getElementsByTagName() into an array and then traverse that array:
// .....
$brs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('br');

$brsArray = iterator_to_array($brs, true);

foreach ($brsArray as $node) {
    //.....

