# How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?

Tags: php, serialization, domdocument

I'm the function below, I'm struggling to output the DOMDocument without it appending the XML, HTML, *body* and *p* tag wrappers before the output of the content. The suggested fix:

```
$postarray['post_content'] = $d->saveXML($d->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0));
```

Only works when the content has no block level elements inside it. However, when it does, as in the example below  with the h1 element, the resulting output from saveXML is truncated to...

> <p>If you like</p>

I've been pointed to this post as a possible workaround, but I can't understand how to implement it into this solution (see commented out attempts below).

Any suggestions?

```
function rseo_decorate_keyword($postarray) {
    global $post;
    $keyword = "Jasmine Tea"
    $content = "If you like <h1>jasmine tea</h1> you will really like it with Jasmine Tea flavors. This is the last ocurrence of the phrase jasmine tea within the content. If there are other instances of the keyword jasmine tea within the text what happens to jasmine tea."
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    @$d->loadHTML($content);
    $x = new DOMXpath($d);
    $count = $x->evaluate("count(//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '$keyword') and (ancestor::b or ancestor::strong)])");
    if ($count > 0) return $postarray;
    $nodes = $x->query("//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '$keyword') and not(ancestor::h1) and not(ancestor::h2) and not(ancestor::h3) and not(ancestor::h4) and not(ancestor::h5) and not(ancestor::h6) and not(ancestor::b) and not(ancestor::strong)]");
    if ($nodes && $nodes->length) {
        $node = $nodes->item(0);
        // Split just before the keyword
        $keynode = $node->splitText(strpos($node->textContent, $keyword));
        // Split after the keyword
        $node->nextSibling->splitText(strlen($keyword));
        // Replace keyword with <b>keyword</b>
        $replacement = $d->createElement('strong', $keynode->textContent);
        $keynode->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $keynode);
    }
$postarray['post_content'] = $d->saveXML($d->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0));
//  $postarray['post_content'] = $d->saveXML($d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(1));
//  $postarray['post_content'] = $d->saveXML($d->getElementsByTagName('body')->childNodes);
return $postarray;
}
```

Answer (score 271):

All of these answers are now *wrong*, because as of PHP 5.4 and Libxml 2.6  [`loadHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) now has a `$option` parameter which instructs Libxml about how it should parse the content.

Therefore, if we load the HTML with these options

```
$html->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

when doing `saveHTML()` there will be no `doctype`, no `<html>`, and no `<body>`.

> `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` turns off the automatic adding of implied html/body elements
>   `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` prevents a default doctype being added when one is not found.

Full documentation about Libxml parameters is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php)

(Note that `loadHTML` docs say that Libxml 2.6 is needed, but `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` is only available in Libxml 2.7.8 and `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` is available in Libxml 2.7.7)

Comment: This doesn't work with PHP 5.4 and Libxml 2.9.  loadHTML doesn't accept any options :(

Comment: Note that this is not quite perfect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493678/loadhtml-libxml-html-noimplied-on-an-html-fragment-generates-incorrect-tags

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn’t seem to be a good solution at all (at least not in practice). It really shouldn’t be the accepted answer. Besides the mentioned issues, there’s also a [nasty encoding issue](https://3v4l.org/LJjQF) with `DOMDocument` that also affects the code in this answer. Afaik, `DOMDocument` always interprets input data as latin-1 *unless the input specifies a different charset*. In other words: The `<meta charset="…">` tag seems to be needed for input data that is not latin-1. Otherwise the output will be broken for e. g. UTF-8 multibyte characters.

Comment: In a system that doesn't provide clean best practice solutions for common use cases the best solution is the one working best for most. The solution should work for elements with no siblings on the first level, shouldn't it? The encoding issue is yet another system flaw in my opinion and can be workarounded using `mb_convert_encoding` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/2477364 I'd say we're in need of proper single-HTML-element handling. `echo`ing HTML elements together is so 2000.

Comment: LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED also messes up the HTML code by removing the tabs, indents and the line breaks

Comment: This will cause issues:  '<p>First Paragraph</p><p>Second Paragraph</p>'  will be converted to '<p>First Paragraph<p></p>Second Paragraph</p>  Take not of the two innter paragraph tags.

Answer (score 77):

Just remove the nodes directly after loading the document with loadHTML():

```
# remove <!DOCTYPE 
$doc->removeChild($doc->doctype);           

# remove <html><body></body></html> 
$doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);
```

Comment: should be noted that this works if <body> has only one child node.

Comment: Thank you for this! I just added another snip at the bottom to handle empty nodes.

Comment: The code to remove `<!DOCTYPE`  works. The second line breaks if `<body>` has more than one child note.

Comment: In some cases it may fail - try `$doc->documentElement` instead of `$doc->firstChild`

Answer (score 29):

The issue with the top answer is that **`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` is unstable**.

It can reorder elements (particularly, moving the top element's closing tag to the bottom of the document), add random `p` tags, and perhaps a variety of other issues[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493678). It may remove the `html` and `body` tags for you, but at the cost of unstable behavior. In production, that's a red flag. In short:

**Don't use `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`**. **Instead, use `substr`**.

---

Think about it. The lengths of `<html><body>` and `</body></html>` are fixed and at both ends of the document - their sizes never change, and neither do their positions. This allows us to use `substr` to cut them away:

```
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

echo substr($dom->saveHTML(), 12, -15); // the star of this operation
```

(**THIS IS NOT THE FINAL SOLUTION HOWEVER! See below for the complete answer**, keep reading for context)

We cut `12` away from the start of the document because `<html><body>` = 12 characters (`<<>>+html+body` = 4+4+4), and we go backwards and cut 15 off the end because `\n</body></html>` = 15 characters (`\n+//+<<>>+body+html` =  1 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 4)

Notice that I still use `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` omit the `!DOCTYPE` from being included. First, this simplifies the `substr` removal of the HTML/BODY tags. Second, we don't remove the doctype with `substr` because we don't know if the '[`default doctype`](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-html-nodefdtd)' will always be something of a fixed length. But, most importantly, `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` stops the DOM parser from applying a non-HTML5 doctype to the document - which at least prevents the parser from treating elements it doesn't recognize as loose text.

We know for a fact that the HTML/BODY tags are of fixed lengths and positions, and we know that constants like `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` are never removed without some type of deprecation notice, so the above method should roll well into the future, **BUT**...

---

...the only caveat is that the DOM implementation *could* change the way in HTML/BODY tags are placed within the document - for instance, removing the newline at the end of the document, adding spaces between the tags, or adding newlines.

This can be remedied by searching for the positions of the opening and closing tags for `body`, and using those offsets as for our lengths to trim off. We use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the offsets from the front and back, respectively:

```
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$trim_off_front = strpos($dom->saveHTML(),'<body>') + 6;
// PositionOf<body> + 6 = Cutoff offset after '<body>'
// 6 = Length of '<body>'

$trim_off_end = (strrpos($dom->saveHTML(),'</body>')) - strlen($dom->saveHTML());
// ^ PositionOf</body> - LengthOfDocument = Relative-negative cutoff offset before '</body>'

echo substr($dom->saveHTML(), $trim_off_front, $trim_off_end);
```

---

**In closing, a repeat of the final, future-proof answer**:

```
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$trim_off_front = strpos($dom->saveHTML(),'<body>') + 6;
$trim_off_end = (strrpos($dom->saveHTML(),'</body>')) - strlen($dom->saveHTML());

echo substr($dom->saveHTML(), $trim_off_front, $trim_off_end);
```

No doctype, no html tag, no body tag. We can only hope the DOM parser will receive a fresh coat of paint soon and we can more directly eliminate these unwanted tags.

Comment: Great answer, one small comment, why not `$html = $dom -> saveHTML();` instead of `$dom -> saveHTML();` repeatedly?

Comment: Great explanation! mermshaus mentioned in a comment under the previous answer above already that "DOMDocument always interprets input data as latin-1 unless the input specifies a different charset. In other words: The <meta charset="…"> tag seems to be needed for input data that is not latin-1. Otherwise the output will be broken for e. g. UTF-8 multibyte characters."

Answer (score 21):

Use `saveXML()` instead, and pass the documentElement as an argument to it.

```
$innerHTML = '';
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $innerHTML .= $document->saveXML($child);
}
echo $innerHTML;
```

http://php.net/domdocument.savexml

Comment: That's better, but I'm still getting <html><body><p> wrapping the contents.

Comment: [As of PHP 5.3.6, you can use `saveHTML` as well](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39771) ([example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/obvdaS))

Comment: It should be noted that saveXML() will save XHTML, not HTML.

Comment: @Scott: that's really strange.  It shows what you're trying to do right there in the examples section.  Are you sure that you don't have that HTML in your DOM?  Exactly what HTML is in your DOMDocument?  It could be that we need to access a child node.

Comment: @Jonah it's not strange. When you do `loadHTML` libxml uses the HTML parser module and that will insert the missing HTML skeleton. Consequently, `$dom->documentElement` will be the root HTML element. I have fixed your example code. It should now do what Scott is asking for.

Comment: #Gordon - That's much better. Only have the p tags wrapper now, but I can live with that. Unless you know how to remove that as well :)

Comment: @Scott that would be the innerHTML of the node. Unfortunately, there is no built in method for that. There is a Userland function for it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument

Comment: @Gordon, I've updated the question with the suggestions. When the document contains block level elements, the 'p' tag suggestion fails.

Comment: @Scott: I made a small change to the code, try it.  saveXML's first argument must be a DOMNode.  Fortunately, DOMText extends DOMNode.  It just might work.

Comment: @Gordon, I was really hoping that would work. It still returns only "if you like" and cuts off the rest.

Comment: @Scott: tested, doesn't work.  The reason is, when you load the HTML, it puts that first phrase inside of a paragraph.  There rest is outside of the paragraph.  `echo $document->saveHTML();` and see for yourself.  Apparently the problem is (as @lonesomeday said), it's manipulating the markup on load.

Comment: @Scott: you may have to go with @lonesomeday's answer.  It seems that loadHTML is messing things up in an unavoidable sort of way.  Either that or don't put block tags inside?  It's invalid HTML anyway.

Comment: @Jonah, see my last comment on @lonesomeday's answer. I'm not sure why, but that method is completely failing for me.

Comment: @Scott: are you sure you did it right?  Could you post the code you used?  But I would really recommend that you just use valid HTML instead.

Comment: @Jonah, It looks like you have updated your answer with the innerHTML bits. I have not tried that yet. Lemme check :)

Answer (score 18):

use DOMDocumentFragment

```
$html = 'what you want';
$doc = new DomDocument();
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($html);
$doc->appendChild($fragment);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This works for me, both older and newer than version Libxml 2.7.7. Why would this be for pre php5.4 solely?

Comment: This should have more votes.  Great option for versions of libxml that don't support LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

It's 2017, and for this 2011 Question I don't like any of the answers.
Lots of regex, big classes, loadXML etc...

Easy solution which solves the known problems:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( '<html><body>'.mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8').'</body></html>' , LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$html = substr(trim($dom->saveHTML()),12,-14);
```

Easy, Simple, Solid, Fast. This code will work regarding HTML tags and encoding like:

```
$html = '<p>äöü</p><p>ß</p>';
```

If anybody finds an error , please tell, I will use this myself.

**Edit**, Other valid options that work without errors (very similar to ones already given):

```
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$saved_dom = trim($dom->saveHTML());
$start_dom = stripos($saved_dom,'<body>')+6;
$html = substr($saved_dom,$start_dom,strripos($saved_dom,'</body>') - $start_dom );
```

You could add body yourself to prevent any strange thing on the furure.

Thirt option:

```
 $mock = new DOMDocument;
 $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
  foreach ($body->childNodes as $child){
     $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
  }
$html = trim($mock->saveHTML());
```

Comment: You should improve your answer by avoiding the more expensive `mb_convert_encoding` and instead adding `<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>` and modifying `substr` accordingly. Btw, yours is the most elegant solution here. Upvoted.

Answer (score 15):

A neat trick is to use [`loadXML`](http://php.net/domdocument.loadxml) and then [`saveHTML`](http://php.net/domdocument.savehtml).  The `html` and `body` tags are inserted at the `load` stage, not the `save` stage.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<p>My DOMDocument contents are here</p>');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

NB that this is a bit hacky and you should use Jonah's answer if you can get it to work.

Comment: This will fail for invalid HTML though.

Comment: @Gordon Exactly why I put the disclaimer at the bottom!

Comment: When I try this, and echo $dom->saveHTML(), it just returns an empty string. As if loadXML($content) is empty. When I do the same with $dom->loadHTML($content), then echo $dom->saveXML() I get the content as expected.

Comment: Using loadXML when willing to load HTMl is thumb. Especially because LoadXML does no know how to handle HTML.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a bit late in the club but didn't want to *not* share a method I've found out about. First of all I've got the right versions for loadHTML() to accept these nice options, but `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` didn't work on my system. Also users report problems with the parser (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26565172/367456) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29493678/367456)).

The solution I created actually is pretty simple.

HTML to be loaded is put in a `<div>` element so it has a container containing all nodes to be loaded.

Then this container element is removed from the document (but the **DOMElement** of it still exists).

Then all direct children from the document are removed. This includes any added `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags (effectively `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` option) as well as the `<!DOCTYPE html ... loose.dtd">` declaration (effectively `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`).

Then all direct children of the container are added to the document again and it can be output.

```
$str = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><p>Nunc vel vehicula ante.</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML("<div>$str</div>");

$container = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);

$container = $container->parentNode->removeChild($container);

while ($doc->firstChild) {
    $doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);
}

while ($container->firstChild ) {
    $doc->appendChild($container->firstChild);
}

$htmlFragment = $doc->saveHTML();
```

XPath works as usual, just take care that there are multiple document elements now, so not a single root node:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('/p') as $element)
{   #                   ^- note the single slash "/"
    # ... each of the two <p> element
```

---

- PHP 5.4.36-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 (cli) (built: Dec 21 2014 20:28:53)

Comment: it didn't work for me with more complex HTML source.
It also removed given part of the HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Okay I found a more elegant solution, but it's just tedious:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
@$d->loadHTML($yourcontent);
...
// do your manipulation, processing, etc of it blah blah blah
...
// then to save, do this
$x = new DOMXPath($d);
$everything = $x->query("body/*"); // retrieves all elements inside body tag
if ($everything->length > 0) { // check if it retrieved anything in there
      $output = '';
      foreach ($everything as $thing) {
           $output .= $d->saveXML($thing);
      }
      echo $output; // voila, no more annoying html wrappers or body tag
}
```

Alright, hopefully this does not omit anything and helps somebody?

Comment: Doesn't handle the case when loadHTML load a string without markup

Answer (score 4):

None of the other solutions at the time of this writing (June, 2012) were able to completely meet my needs, so I wrote one which handles the following cases:

- Accepts plain-text content which has no tags, as well as HTML content.
- Does not append any tags (including `<doctype>`, `<xml>`, `<html>`, `<body>`, and `<p>` tags)
- Leaves anything wrapped in `<p>` alone.
- Leaves empty text alone.

So here is a solution which fixes those issues:

```
class DOMDocumentWorkaround
{
    /**
     * Convert a string which may have HTML components into a DOMDocument instance.
     *
     * @param string $html - The HTML text to turn into a string.
     * @return \DOMDocument - A DOMDocument created from the given html.
     */
    public static function getDomDocumentFromHtml($html)
    {
        $domDocument = new DOMDocument();

        // Wrap the HTML in <div> tags because loadXML expects everything to be within some kind of tag.
        // LIBXML_NOERROR and LIBXML_NOWARNING mean this will fail silently and return an empty DOMDocument if it fails.
        $domDocument->loadXML('<div>' . $html . '</div>', LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

        return $domDocument;
    }

    /**
     * Convert a DOMDocument back into an HTML string, which is reasonably close to what we started with.
     *
     * @param \DOMDocument $domDocument
     * @return string - The resulting HTML string
     */
    public static function getHtmlFromDomDocument($domDocument)
    {
        // Convert the DOMDocument back to a string.
        $xml = $domDocument->saveXML();

        // Strip out the XML declaration, if one exists
        $xmlDeclaration = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
        if (substr($xml, 0, strlen($xmlDeclaration)) == $xmlDeclaration) {
            $xml = substr($xml, strlen($xmlDeclaration));
        }

        // If the original HTML was empty, loadXML collapses our <div></div> into <div/>. Remove it.
        if ($xml == "<div/>\n") {
            $xml = '';
        }
        else {
            // Remove the opening <div> tag we previously added, if it exists.
            $openDivTag = "<div>";
            if (substr($xml, 0, strlen($openDivTag)) == $openDivTag) {
                $xml = substr($xml, strlen($openDivTag));
            }

            // Remove the closing </div> tag we previously added, if it exists.
            $closeDivTag = "</div>\n";
            $closeChunk = substr($xml, -strlen($closeDivTag));
            if ($closeChunk == $closeDivTag) {
                $xml = substr($xml, 0, -strlen($closeDivTag));
            }
        }

        return $xml;
    }
}
```

I also wrote some tests which would live in that same class:

```
public static function testHtmlToDomConversions($content)
{
    // test that converting the $content to a DOMDocument and back does not change the HTML
    if ($content !== self::getHtmlFromDomDocument(self::getDomDocumentFromHtml($content))) {
        echo "Failed\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "Succeeded\n";
    }
}

public static function testAll()
{
    self::testHtmlToDomConversions('<p>Here is some sample text</p>');
    self::testHtmlToDomConversions('<div>Lots of <div>nested <div>divs</div></div></div>');
    self::testHtmlToDomConversions('Normal Text');
    self::testHtmlToDomConversions(''); //empty
}
```

You can check that it works for yourself. `DomDocumentWorkaround::testAll()` returns this:

```
    Succeeded
    Succeeded
    Succeeded
    Succeeded
```

Comment: HTML =/= XML, you should use the HTML loader for HTML.

Answer (score 4):

If the flags solution answered by **Alessandro Vendruscolo** doesn't works, you may try this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

//do your stuff..

$finalHtml = '';
$bodyTag = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($bodyTag->childNodes as $rootLevelTag) {
    $finalHtml .= $dom->saveHTML($rootLevelTag);
}
echo $finalHtml;
```

`$bodyTag` will contain your full processed HTML code without all those HTML wraps, except for the `<body>` tag, which is the root of your content. Then you can use a regex or a trim function to remove it from the final string (after `saveHTML`) or, like in the case above, iterate over all of its childen, saving their content into a temporary variable `$finalHtml` and return it (what i believe being safer).

Answer (score 4):

I am struggling with this on RHEL7 running PHP 5.6.25 and LibXML 2.9. (Old stuff in 2018, I know, but that is Red Hat for you.)

I have found that the much upvoted solution suggested by *Alessandro Vendruscolo* breaks the HTML by rearranging tags. I.e.:

```
<p>First.</p><p>Second.</p>'
```

becomes:

```
<p>First.<p>Second.</p></p>'
```

This goes for both the options he suggests you use: `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` and `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`.

The solution suggested by *Alex* goes half way to solve it, but it does not work if `<body>` has more than one child node.

The solution that works for me is the follwing:

First, to load the DOMDocument, I use:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument()
$doc->loadHTML($content);
```

To save the document after massaging the DOMDocument, I use:

```
// remove <!DOCTYPE 
$doc->removeChild($doc->doctype);  
$content = $doc->saveHTML();
// remove <html><body></body></html> 
$content = str_replace('<html><body>', '', $content);
$content = str_replace('</body></html>', '', $content);
```

I am the first to agree that this this is not a very elegant solution - but it works.

Comment: This isn't going to work - if the $content includes <head> information then it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function

```
$layout = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|head|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $layout);
```

Comment: There may be some readers who have stumbled across this post via [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), have decided not to use regex to parse their HTML and use a DOM parser instead, and end up potentially needing a regex answer to achieve a complete solution... ironic

Comment: I do't understand why noboy just returns the content of BODY. Is that tag not suppossed to always be present when the parser adds the whole document header/doctype? The regex above would even be shorter.

Comment: @boksiora "it does the job" - then why are we using DOM parser methods in the first place?

Comment: @naomik i haven't said not to use a DOM parser, there are of course many different way to achieve the same result, its up to you, at the time i used this function i had a problem with the built-in php dom parser, which was not parsing html5 correctly.

Comment: I had to use `preg_replace` because using DOMDocument-based methods of removing the html and body tags were not preserving the UTF-8 encoding :(

Answer (score 3):

Much like other members, I first revelled in the simplicity and awesome power of @Alessandro Vendruscolo answer. The ability to simply pass in some flagged constants to the constructor seemed too good to be true. For me it was. I have the correct versions of both LibXML as well as PHP however no matter what it still would add the HTML tag to the node structure of the Document object.

My solution worked way better than using the...

```
$html->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Flags or....

```
# remove <!DOCTYPE 
$doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);            

# remove <html><body></body></html>
$doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);
```

Node Removal, which gets messy without a structured order in the DOM. Again code fragments have no way to predetermine DOM structure.

I started this journey wanting a simple way to do DOM traversal how JQuery does it or at least in some fashion that had a structured data set either singly linked, doubly linked or tree'd node traversal. I didn't care how as long as I could parse a string the way HTML does and also have the amazing power of the node entity class properties to use along the way.

So far DOMDocument Object has left me wanting... As with many other programmers it seems... I know I have seen a lot of frustration in this question so since I FINALLY.... (after roughly 30 hours of try and fail type testing) I have found a way to get it all. I hope this helps someone...

**First off, I am cynical of EVERYTHING...** lol...

I would have went a lifetime before agreeing with anyone that a third party class is in anyway needed in this use case. I very much was and am NOT a fan of using any third party class structure however I stumbled onto a great parser. (about 30 times in Google before I gave in so don't feel alone if you avoided it because it looked lame of unofficial in any way...)

If you are using code fragments and need the, code clean and unaffected by the parser in any way, without extra tags being used then use [simplePHPParser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/).

It's amazing and acts a lot like JQuery. I not often impressed but this class makes use of a lot of good tools and I have had no parsing errors as of yet. I am a huge fan of being able to do what this class does.

You can find its files to download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/), its startup instructions [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), and its API [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm). I highly recommend using this class with its simple methods that can do a `.find(".className")` the same way a JQuery find method would be used or even familiar methods such as `getElementByTagName()` or `getElementById()`...

When you save out a node tree in this class it doesn't add anything at all. You can simply say `$doc->save();` and it outputs the entire tree to a string without any fuss.

I will now be using this parser for all, non-capped-bandwidth, projects in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this topic to find a way to remove HTML wrapper. Using `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` works great, but I have a problem with utf-8.  After much effort I found a solution. I post it bellow for anyone has the same problem.

The problem caused because of `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

**The problem:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $document, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$dom->saveHTML();
```

**Solution 1:**

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($document, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$dom->loadHTML($document, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
```

Comment: I find it nice that you share your findings, but Solution 2 is already present with this exact questions here and Solution 1 is elsewhere. Also for the Problem of Solution 1 the answer given is unclear. I honour your good intentions, nbut please be aware that it can create a lot of noise as well hindering others to find the solutions they are looking for which I guess is kinda the opposite of what you want to achieve with your answer. Stackoverflow works best if you handle one question at a time. Just a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `<meta>` tag will trigger the fixing behavior of `DOMDocument`. The good part is that you don't need to add that tag at all. If you wan't to use an encoding of your choosing just pass it as a constructor argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$node = $doc->createElement('div', 'Hello World');
$doc->appendChild($node);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Thanks to [@Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776954/set-php-dom-to-not-correct-html-when-html-head-body-tags-are-not-set/16778124?noredirect=1#16778124)

Answer (score 2):

I had this requirement, too, and liked the solution posted by Alex above.  There are a couple of issues, though - if the `<body>` element contains more than one child element, the resulting document will only contain only the first child element of `<body>`, not all of them.   Also, I needed the stripping to handle things conditionally - only when you had document with the HTML headings.  So I refined it as follows.  Instead of removing `<body>`, I transformed it to a `<div>`, and stripped out the XML declaration and `<html>`.

```
function strip_html_headings($html_doc)
{
    if (is_null($html_doc))
    {
        // might be better to issue an exception, but we silently return
        return;
    }

    // remove <!DOCTYPE 
    if (!is_null($html_doc->firstChild) &&
        $html_doc->firstChild->nodeType == XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE)
    {
        $html_doc->removeChild($html_doc->firstChild);     
    }

    if (!is_null($html_doc->firstChild) &&
        strtolower($html_doc->firstChild->tagName) == 'html' &&
        !is_null($html_doc->firstChild->firstChild) &&
        strtolower($html_doc->firstChild->firstChild->tagName) == 'body')
    {
        // we have 'html/body' - replace both nodes with a single "div"        
        $div_node = $html_doc->createElement('div');

        // copy all the child nodes of 'body' to 'div'
        foreach ($html_doc->firstChild->firstChild->childNodes as $child)
        {
            // deep copies each child node, with attributes
            $child = $html_doc->importNode($child, true);
            // adds node to 'div''
            $div_node->appendChild($child);
        }

        // replace 'html/body' with 'div'
        $html_doc->removeChild($html_doc->firstChild);
        $html_doc->appendChild($div_node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have PHP 5.3 and the answers here did not work for me.

`$doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);` replaced all the document with only the first child, I had many paragraphs and only the first was being saved, but the solution gave me a good starting point to write something without `regex` I left some comments and I am pretty sure this can be improved but if someone has the same problem as me it can be a good starting point.

```
function extractDOMContent($doc){
    # remove <!DOCTYPE
    $doc->removeChild($doc->doctype);

    // lets get all children inside the body tag
    foreach ($doc->firstChild->firstChild->childNodes as $k => $v) {
        if($k !== 0){ // don't store the first element since that one will be used to replace the html tag
            $doc->appendChild( clone($v) ); // appending element to the root so we can remove the first element and still have all the others
        }
    }
    // replace the body tag with the first children
    $doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);
    return $doc;
}
```

Then we could use it like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$doc->loadHTML('<p>Some html here</p><p>And more html</p><p>and some html</p>');
$doc = extractDOMContent($doc);
```

Note that [`appendChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) accepts a [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) so we do not need to create new elements, we can just reuse existing ones that implement `DOMNode`such as [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) this can be important to keep code "sane" when manipulating multiple HTML/XML documents

Comment: This won't work for fragments, only for a single child-element that you want to make the first-child of the document. This is pretty limited and effectively not doing the job of the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` as it does that only partially. Removing the doctype is effectively `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`.

Answer (score 2):

I face 3 problems with `DOMDocument` class.

1- This class loads html with ISO encoding and utf-8 characters not showing in output.

2- Even if we give ‍‍‍`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` flag to loadHtml method, until our input html does not contain a root tag, it will not be parse correctly.

3- This class considers the HTML5 tags invalid.

So I've override this class to solve these problems and I changed some of the methods.

```php
class DOMEditor extends DOMDocument
{
    /**
     * Temporary wrapper tag , It should be an unusual tag to avoid problems
     */
    protected $tempRoot = 'temproot';

    public function __construct($version = '1.0', $encoding = 'UTF-8')
    {
        //turn off html5 errors
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        parent::__construct($version, $encoding);
    }

    public function loadHTML($source, $options = LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD)
    {
        // this is a bitwise check if LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED is set
        if ($options & LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED) {
            // it loads the content with a temporary wrapper tag and utf-8 encoding
            parent::loadHTML("<{$this->tempRoot}>" . mb_convert_encoding($source, 'HTML', 'UTF-8') . "</{$this->tempRoot}>", $options);
        } else {
            // it loads the content with utf-8 encoding and default options
            parent::loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($source, 'HTML', 'UTF-8'), $options);
        }
    }

    private function unwrapTempRoot($output)
    {
        if ($this->firstChild->nodeName === $this->tempRoot) {
            return substr($output, strlen($this->tempRoot) + 2, -strlen($this->tempRoot) - 4);
        }
        return $output;
    }

    public function saveHTML(DOMNode $node = null)
    {
        $html = html_entity_decode(parent::saveHTML($node));
        if (is_null($node)) {
            $html = $this->unwrapTempRoot($html);
        }
        return $html;
    }

    public function saveXML(DOMNode $node = null, $options = null)
    {
        if (is_null($node)) {
            return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' . PHP_EOL . $this->saveHTML();
        }
        return parent::saveXML($node);
    }

}
```

Now im using `DOMEditor` instead of `DOMDocument` and it has worked well for me so far

```php
        $editor = new DOMEditor();
        $editor->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        // works like a charm!
        echo $editor->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Your point 1. is solved by using mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); before using loadHTML() and the 2.nd by having a DIV tag around in your helper function, around mb_convert_encoding() you use for example. Worked out for me good enough. Indeed if no DIV is present, then it automatically adds a paragraph in my case which is inconvenient since usually they have some margin applied (bootstrap..)

Answer (score 2):

After reading lots of code about this topic, I ended up with the following solution that works very well for me and is easy to understand.

It fixes unwanted Doctype and `<html>` and `<body>` as well as encoding issues.

This code assumes that `$htmlContent` is encoded in `utf-8`.

```php
$htmlContent = "<h1>This is a heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p>";

// 1.) Load the html
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='charset=utf-8' /><div>$htmlContent</div>");

// 2.) Do you logic
$dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]->setAttribute('class', 'happy');

// 3.) Render the html
$wrapperNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
$renderedHtml = $dom->saveHTML($wrapperNode);
// If you want to keep the wrapper div
echo $renderedHtml;
// Or remove the wrapper <div>
echo substr(trim($renderedHtml), 5, -6);
```

The key take aways are:

- loadHTML assumes content to be iso-8859-1, if this is not the case, you need to add encoding information.
- Wrap your html code in a div and render just this div, you can remove it with substring if you don’t want to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

My universal solution independent of how the HTML was loaded:

```
function getNodeHtml(DOMNode $node, $outer = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $node = $node instanceof DOMDocument ? $node->documentElement : $node;
    foreach(($outer ? array($node) : $node->childNodes) as $n) {
        $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($n->cloneNode(true), true));
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Sample results:

- `<p>foo   bar   </p>` ━▶ `<p>foo   bar   </p>`
- `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>` ━▶ `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>`
- `<p>foo </p> <p> bar</p>` ━▶ `<p>foo </p> <p> bar</p>`
- `Hello!` ━▶ `Hello!`
- `<html><body><b>foo</b></body></html>` ━▶ `<html><body><b>foo</b></body></html>`

Comment: This does absolutely nothing... Why not just use "$doc->saveHTML()" ?

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this issue as well.

Unfortunately, I did not felt comfortably using any of the solutions provided in this thread, so I went to check one that would satisfy me.

Here's what I made up and it works without issues:

```
$domxpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);

/** @var \DOMNodeList $subset */
$subset = $domxpath->query('descendant-or-self::body/*');

$html = '';
foreach ($subset as $domElement) {
    /** @var $domElement \DOMElement */
    $html .= $domDocument->saveHTML($domElement);
}
```

In essense it works in similar way to most of the solutions provided here, but instead of doing manual labor it uses xpath selector to select all the elements within the body and concatenates their html code.

Comment: Like all solutions here, it doesn't work for every case : if the loaded string didn't start with markup, <p></p> has been added, then your code doesn't work, since it'll add the <p></p> markup in the saved content

Comment: To be fair, I haven't tested it with raw text, but in theory should work. For your specific case you may need to change the xpath to something like ```descendant-or-self::body/p/*```.

Answer (score 0):

my server got php 5.3 and can't upgrade so those options

```
LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD
```

are not for me.

To solve this i tell to the SaveXML Function to print the Body element and then just replace the "body" with "div"

here is my code, hope it's helping someone:

```
<? 
$html = "your html here";
$tabContentDomDoc = new DOMDocument();
$tabContentDomDoc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$html);
$tabContentDomDoc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$tabContentDomDocBody = $tabContentDomDoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
if(is_object($tabContentDomDocBody)){
    echo (str_replace("body","div",$tabContentDomDoc->saveXML($tabContentDomDocBody)));
}
?>
```

the utf-8 is for Hebrew support.

Answer (score 0):

Alex answer is correct, but might cause following error on empty nodes:

> Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::removeChild() must be an instance of
>   DOMNode

Here comes my little mod:

```
    $output = '';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($htmlString); //feed with html here

    if (isset($doc->firstChild)) {

        /* remove doctype */

        $doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);

        /* remove html and body */

        if (isset($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild)) {
            $doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);
            $output = trim($doc->saveHTML());
        }
    }
    return $output;
```

Adding the trim() is also a good idea to remove whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe too late. But maybe somebody (like me) still has this issue.
 So, none of the above worked for me. Because $dom->loadHTML also close open tags as well, not only add html and body tags.
So add a < div > element is not working for me, because I have sometimes like 3-4 unclosed div in the html piece.
My solution:
1.) Add marker to cut, then load the html piece

```
$html_piece = "[MARK]".$html_piece."[/MARK]";
$dom->loadHTML($html_piece);
```

2.) do whatever you want with the document
3.) save html

```
$new_html_piece = $dom->saveHTML();
```

4.) before you return it, remove < p >< /p > tags from marker, strangely it is only appear on [MARK] but not on [/MARK]...!?

```
$new_html_piece = preg_replace( "/<p[^>]*?>(\[MARK\]|\s)*?<\/p>/", "[MARK]" , $new_html_piece );
```

5.) remove everything before and after marker

```
$pattern_contents = '{\[MARK\](.*?)\[\/MARK\]}is';
if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $new_html_piece, $matches)) {
    $new_html_piece = $matches[1];
}
```

6.) return it

```
return $new_html_piece;
```

It would be a lot easier if LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED worked for me. It schould, but it is not. PHP 5.4.17, libxml Version  2.7.8. 
I find really strange, I use the HTML DOM parser and then, to fix this "thing" I have to use regex... The whole point was, not to use regex ;)

Comment: Looks dangerous what you do here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29499718/367456 should do the job for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper/29499718#29499718) will not work for me.

As I said:
"So add a < div > element is not working for me, because I have sometimes like 3-4 unclosed div in the html piece"

For some reason, the DOMDocument want to close all "not closed" elements. In may case, I will get a fregment within a shortcode or other marker, remove the fregment and I want to manipulate the other piece of the document, when I'm done with that, I will insert the fregment back.

Comment: It should be possible to leave the div element out and operate on the body element after loading your own content instead. The body element should be added implicitly when you load a fragment.

Comment: My problem is, my fregment containt unclosed tag. It should be remain unclosed and DOMDocument will close those elements. Fregment like: `< div >< div > ... < /div >`. I still looking for solutions.

Comment: Hmm, I think div tags always have a closing pair. Perhaps Tidy can handle that, it can work with fragments, too.

Comment: It should and in the end it will. This "markers" is from the enduser. I use this markers eg. for a lazy loading plugin to ignore a part of the page. I do not know where the user will add the marks. It shouldn't metter. What my code need to do, replace all < img src to 1px blank placeholder but ignore the fregment between markers.

Comment: Sound more like a custom filtering of the underlying nodes. The markers will be within text-nodes. This is a bit more advanced, text node processing (but in the meaning of editing these and inserting element nodes there in I have shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8193700/367456 - just referencing, this is *not* exactly what you're looking for but it *might* give you some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone using Drupal, there's a built in function to do this:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_dom_serialize/7.x

Code for reference:

```
function filter_dom_serialize($dom_document) {
  $body_node = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
  $body_content = '';

  if ($body_node !== NULL) {
    foreach ($body_node->getElementsByTagName('script') as $node) {
      filter_dom_serialize_escape_cdata_element($dom_document, $node);
    }

    foreach ($body_node->getElementsByTagName('style') as $node) {
      filter_dom_serialize_escape_cdata_element($dom_document, $node, '/*', '*/');
    }

    foreach ($body_node->childNodes as $child_node) {
      $body_content .= $dom_document->saveXML($child_node);
    }
    return preg_replace('|<([^> ]*)/>|i', '<$1 />', $body_content);
  }
  else {
    return $body_content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Usig this function from the Drupal API works fine on my Drupal 7 site. I guess those not using Drupal can just copy the function into their own site - as there is nothing Drupal-specific about this.

Answer (score -1):

```
#remove doctype tag
$doc->removeChild($doc->doctype); 

#remove html & body tags
$html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
$body = $html->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
foreach($body->childNodes as $child) {
    $doc->appendChild($child);
}
$doc->removeChild($html);
```

Comment: Care to share why the -1?

Answer (score -1):

You can use tidy with show-body-only:

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$htmlBody = $tidy->repairString($html, [
  'indent' =>  true,
  'output-xhtml' => true,
  'show-body-only' => true
], 'utf8');
```

But, remeber: tidy remove some tags like Font Awesome icons: [Problems Indenting HTML(5) with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172824/problems-indenting-html5-with-php)

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution that helped me:

```
$content = str_replace(array('<html>','</html>') , '' , $doc->saveHTML());
```