# How to prevent the doctype from being added to the HTML?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, doctype

I have been working on this tidy-up-messy-html tags with DOM, but now I realise a bigger problem,

```
$content = '<p><a href="#">this is a link</a></p>';

function tidy_html($content,$allowable_tags = null, $span_regex = null)
{      
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

        // other codes
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}

echo tidy_html($content);
```

It will output the entire DOM,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html><body><p><a href="#">this is a link</a></p></body></html>
```

but I only want something like this in the return,

```
<p><a href="#">this is a link</a></p>
```

I don't want,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
    <html><body>...</body></html>
```

Is this possible??

**EDIT:**

the `innerHTML` simulation generates some strange codes in my database, like `&#13;` , `Â` , `â€™`

```
<p>Monday July 5th 10am - 3.30pm Â£20</p>&#13;
<p>Be one of the first visitors to the ...at this special event.Â</p>&#13;
<p>All participants will receive a free copy of the â€˜Contemporary Art Kitâ€™ produced exclusively for Art on....</p>&#13;
```

the `innerHTML` simulation,

```
$innerHHTML = '';
$nodeBody = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach($nodeBody->childNodes as $child) {
  $innerHTML .= $nodeBody->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
}
```

I found out that the reason it creates the strange codes when there is a break is caused by `saveXML($child)`

So when I have something like this,

```
$content = '<p><br/><a href="#">xx</a></p>
<p><br/><a href="#">xx</a></p>';
```

It will return something like this,

```
<p><a href="#">xx</a></p>&#13;
<p><a href="#">xx</a></p>
```

But I want something this actually,

```
<p><a href="#">xx</a></p>
<p><a href="#">xx</a></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working on a fragment, you normally need only the body contents.

DomDocument in PHP does not offer something like `innerHTML`. You can simulate it however:

```
$innerHHTML = '';
$nodeBody = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach($nodeBody->childNodes as $child) {
  $innerHTML .= $nodeBody->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
}
```

If you just want to repair a fragment, you can make use of the [tidy library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) as well:

```
$html = tidy_repair_string($html, array('output-xhtml'=>1,'show-body-only'=>1));
```

Comment: got it thank you! I don't know how to incorporate `tidy_repair_string` into my code though... but the `innerHTML` simulation works perfectly!

Comment: just found out that the `innerHTML` simulation generate something strange. Please see my edit above. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like an encoding issue on your end. Ensure you only pump UTF-8 encoded strings into DomDocument. And you could normalize line-breaks as well before. However you should read into the tidy library, it has years of experience and deals with encodings and line-breaks as well.

Comment: I use `tidy_repair_string()` to fix this issue `$fragment = tidy_repair_string($dom->saveHTML(), array('output-xhtml'=>1,'show-body-only'=>1));
 return $fragment;`

Comment: I have to make sure that the server has this `php_tidy` turned on. this could be a problem on a live server as some of them may not have this configured...

Answer (score 0):

Hakre already mentioned the [show-body-only](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#show-body-only) option to HTML Tidy, which is probably what you want.

Ps. [Here's](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/tidy.conf?view=markup) the Tidy config file used by MediaWiki for pretty much just this purpose.