# Parse valid html (php - tidy)

Tags: php, parsing, htmltidy

I want to use tidy plugin but only for one string. The code that I'm using is :

```
tidy_repair_string($string);
```

My problem is that this script is in a file an I just use require once to include him.

But tidy duplicate html, body, title tags (the general tags for a file).

How can only validate my string without return html, etc, etc ?

Example : If my string is `<b><s>Text</b>` I want tidy to return only `<b><s>Text</s></b>`

**NOT :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<b><s>Text</s></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As you already noted in your question, Tidy operates on a full HTML document, so a repaired one contains (if configured) a doctype but always a head section.

You're looking for a HTML fragment, which is not a full HTML document.

This differentiation already contains the solution: Inject your HTML fragment as the body, repair it as a document and then obtain only the children of the body as string. Done. Here is a rather short but already working example:

```
/* Tidy example: Clean a HTML fragment */

$fragment = '<b><s>Text</b>';

$tidy = new Tidy;
$tidy->parseString($fragment);
$tidy->cleanRepair();

$result = implode('', (array) $tidy->body()->child); // <b><s>Text</s></b>
```

If you want to go a step further and validate the HTML fragment (e.g. only valid HTML tags and all tags closed, see as well [tidy configuration](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html)), you can prefix it with the bare minimum HTML so errors and warnings fall into the responsibility of the fragment itself. The status can be obtained then via [`tidy::getStatus()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.getstatus.php):

```
/* Tidy example: Validate a HTML fragment (4 samples) */

$fragments = [
    ['Valid fragment', '<b><s>Text</s></b>'],
    ['Unclosed tag', '<b><s>Text</b>'],
    ['Unknown tag', '<unknown></unknown>'],
    ['Unfinished attribute', '<a href=">link</a>'],
];

$tidy = new Tidy;

foreach ($fragments as list($title, $fragment)) {
    $tidy->parseString("<!DOCTYPE html><title>HTML fragment</title><body>" . $fragment);
    $status = $tidy->getStatus();
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    $result = implode('', (array)$tidy->body()->child);
    printf("%s - Status: %d\n  HTML: %s\n  Repaired: %s\n", $title, $status, $fragment, $result);
}
```

This example will provide the following output demonstrating the meaning of the return value of `getType` in the default configuration:

```
Valid fragment - Status: 0
  HTML: <b><s>Text</s></b>
  Repaired: <b><s>Text</s></b>
Unclosed tag - Status: 1
  HTML: <b><s>Text</b>
  Repaired: <b><s>Text</s></b>
Unknown tag - Status: 2
  HTML: <unknown></unknown>
  Repaired: 
Unfinished attribute - Status: 2
  HTML: <a href=">link</a>
  Repaired: <a href="%3Elink%3C/a%3E"></a>
```

That's more than you've asked for and I only added it as an additional example, e.g. to see if all tags in a string are closed.

Comment: Just seeing [a previous answer of mine, there is a `show-body-only` option with Tidy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6851708/367456).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this works. if not, refer to http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#output-html
for more options

```
$string = tidy_repair_string($string, array(
'output-html' => false,
'doctype' => false));
```

Comment: It doesn't. I'll try to look on sourceforge. Thank you.