# Wrap all HTML tags between h3 tag sets with DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I've got a follow up question to my question that has been answered by Jack:
[Wrap segments of HTML with divs (and generate table of contents from HTML-tags) with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10683421)

I've been trying to add some functionality to the answer above, in order to get the following result.

This is my present HTML:

```
<h3>Subtitle</h3>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
<h3>Another subtile
  <h3>
    <p>Yet another paragraph</p>
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
<h3 class="current">Subtitle</h3>
<div class="ac_pane" style="display:block;">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph</p>
</div>
<h3>Another subtitle</h3>
<div class="ac_pane">
  <p>Yet another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I've been trying to modify the code out of the example above, but can't figure it out:

```
foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $h3) {
    $ac_pane_nodes = array($h3);
    for ($next = $h3->nextSibling; $next && $next->nodeName != 'h3'; $next = $next->nextSibling) {
        $ac_pane_nodes[] = $next;
    }
    $ac_pane = $d->createElement('div');
    $ac_pane->setAttribute('class', 'ac_pane');
    // Here I'm trying to wrap all tags between h3-sets, but am failing!
            $h3->parentNode->appendChild($ac_pane, $h3);
    foreach ($ac_pane_nodes as $node) {
        $ac_pane->appendChild($node);
    }
}
```

Please note that the addition of `class="current"` to the first h3 set, and the addition of `style="display:block;"` to the first `div.ac_pane` is optional, but would be very much appreciated.

Comment: XSLT is what I'd recommend, but doing grouping with it is... complicated to say the least (i.e. grouping consecutive p tags into a single div). It's something to consider. If you are open to an XSLT solution, let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Did you check the link above? That solution does some appropriate grouping, I'd only need to mod it so that it wraps everything excluding the h3 in question... Could you have a look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a key difference between this version and the one in the link. In the linked version, the h2 gets included as part of the nodeset getting wrapped, whereas in this version, the h3 is excluded from the set. That's where you're having an issue. If that hint doesn't cut it, let me know and I'll write a working version for you

Comment: Hi matb33, that's exactly why I'm having troubles. I can't get my head around the inner workings of the code above. I would very, very much appreciate a working version! Could you please do the honors? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, here is a working version. IMO XSLT is still the solution most appropriate to this type of problem (transforming some XML into other XML, really) but I have to admit grouping with regular code is much easier!

I ended up extending the DOM API slightly just to add a utility `insertAfter` method on DOMElement. It could have been done without it, but it's neater:

**UPDATED TO WRAP DIV AROUND ALL TAGS AS REQUESTED IN COMMENTS**

```
<?php

class DOMDocumentExtended extends DOMDocument {
    public function __construct($version = "1.0", $encoding = "UTF-8") {
        parent::__construct($version, $encoding);
        $this->registerNodeClass("DOMElement", "DOMElementExtended");
    }
}

class DOMElementExtended extends DOMElement {
    public function insertAfter($targetNode) {
        if ($targetNode->nextSibling) {
            $targetNode->parentNode->insertBefore($this, $targetNode->nextSibling);
        } else {
            $targetNode->parentNode->appendChild($this);
        }
    }

    public function wrapAround(DOMNodeList $nodeList) {
        while (($node = $nodeList->item(0)) !== NULL) {
            $this->appendChild($node);
        }
    }
}

$doc = new DOMDocumentExtended();
$doc->loadHTML(
    "<h3>Subtitle</h3>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph</p>
    <h3>Another subtile</h3>
    <p>Yet another paragraph</p>"
);

// Grab a nodelist of all h3 tags
$nodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName("h3");

// Iterate over each of these h3 nodes
foreach ($nodeList as $index => $h3) {

    // Special handling for first h3
    if ($index === 0) {
        $h3->setAttribute("class", "current");
    }

    // Create a div node that we'll use as our wrapper
    $div = $doc->createElement("div");
    $div->setAttribute("class", "ac_pane");

    // Special handling for first div wrapper
    if ($index === 0) {
        $div->setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
    }

    // Move next siblings of h3 until we hit another h3
    while ($h3->nextSibling && $h3->nextSibling->localName !== "h3") {
        $div->appendChild($h3->nextSibling);
    }

    // Add the div node right after the h3
    $div->insertAfter($h3);
}

// UPDATE: wrap all child nodes of body in a div
$div = $doc->createElement("div");
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);
$div->wrapAround($body->childNodes);
$body->appendChild($div);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

*Note that loadHTML will add doctype, html and body nodes. [They can be stripped out if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416704/remove-parent-element-keep-all-inner-children-in-domdocument-with-savehtml/10657666#10657666).*

Comment: Thank you so much! I will be testing and trying to implement your code ASAP and will get back to you with approval soon.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works perfectly! Thanks ever so much!

Comment: Just one last little detail: is there a quick and easy way to wrap this newly created html with another div?

Comment: Thank you for everything. Everything works perfectly! A real pro!