# Filter to remove p tag from image inside ACF WYSIWYG + Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, wysiwyg, timber

So I'm displaying some content from ACF WYSIWYG

```
{{  post.get_field('content') }}
```

And I get something like this

```
<p class=p1">Text</p>
<p class=p1">Text<p1>
<p class=p1"><img src="someimagejpg" /><p>
<p class=p1">Text<p1>
```

Everything is fine except for the image wrapped in a p tag.

I search some filters and it looks like the main solution its the following.

Inside functions.php

```
 function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
     $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
     return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('acf_the_content, 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

But this seems not to work on Timber

It looks like Timber has its own way to register filters but it has not work for me either any help will be appreciate it thanks!!

I have tried this on Timber:

```
add_filter( 'timber_context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );

 function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    /* this is where you can add your own functions to twig */

    $twig->addFilter('acf_the_content', new Twig_Filter_Function('filter_ptags_on_images'));
    $twig->addFilter('the_content', new Twig_Filter_Function('filter_ptags_on_images'));

    return $twig;
}
```

Not working

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly still no :( I just used a different layout

Answer (score 0):

You can find your solution in striptags filter:

```
{{ some_html|striptags }}
```

A good thing to know is that you can avoid removing some of the HTML tags, as you might need them, like this:

```
{{ some_html|striptags('<br><p>') }}
```

This will remove all HTML tags except
`<br/>, <br>, <p>, and </p>`

More about this you can find ->[Twig/striptags](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html)

I thought you want to strip them all.
Now here's a tricky way to do it with jQuery using [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)
Only thing you would need to do is within your content just add some class to your img tag as a selector.

I don't have time right now to create some filter but you could have a look at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416704/remove-parent-element-keep-all-inner-children-in-domdocument-with-savehtml) as how to remove wrapping element with PHP and [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) how to create custom twig filter.

Comment: No this doesn't work for this case, given that I still want to keep the <p> in general just remove the one that is wrapping the <img> tag. What you are suggesting will remove all the <p> tags.

Comment: Hey Mario, I have updated my answer there for you. :)