# PHP DOMDocument without the DTD, head, and body tags?

Tags: php, domdocument, doctype

Is it possible to use the DOMDocument class and not allow it to add doc type declarations, head, and body tags? I am writing my current bit of code for a server side include, and it is being rendered on an already well formed page. I don't need additional tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3.6, you can use a node in [`echo $DOMDocument->saveHTML($the_node_you_want_to_show)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php), before that, I've abused `->saveXML()` with minor fixes. You must however have 1 surrounding included node (e.g. output is `<div>...somecontent and nodex....</div>`, or loop through the nodes children if you don't want have 1 surrounding tag;

```
$html = '';
foreach($rootnode->childNodes as $node){
    $html .= $rootnode->ownerdocument->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but wondering how to go from working with a DOMDocument to a node. Do I have to loop through the document variable and cast each part I want to keep as a separate node? If that is the case, how do I use your method to save multiple nodes to the HTML document?

Comment: Use any of the DOM function you want to retrieve the node, but most likely, you want the contents of the `<body>` tag, so something likely `$rootnode = $dom->getELementsByTagName('body')->item(0);`. Other options involve indeed stepping through `->childNodes`, using `DOMXPath`, `->getElementById()`, etc.

Comment: It does not appear as though you can use DOM elements independently from a document. If you cannot remove these items from a document, then how can this work?

Comment: Why do you need to _remove_ them from a document? The only time I need to do that is when I echo out the (X)HTML/XML string, at which point that is fine. What is it you want to achieve that needs 'seperate' nodes?

Comment: Hm, I'm now thinking you might think you can't 'insert' the node into another document. Which is perfectly possible with `->importNode()`, so deeper functionality does not need to 'know' about your 'main' document.

Comment: It seems like you are saying to publish the node to the document, but the document is what publishes the unwanted tags in the first place.

Maybe I don't need to work with the nodes outside of the document, as long as I can publish only the nodes that I need. This needs to happen dynamically, so I am unable to do getElementsByTagName because I cannot be sure which tags will contain all the content. I am having the additional problem of not being able to log or var_dump the domdocument elements to inspect them.

Comment: I can loop through the document, and clone the nodes that I want. However if I append them to another document, I wind up back where I started since the domdocument class creates those tags in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13127/discussion-between-wrikken-and-nodirtyrockstar)

Answer (score 5):

What @Wrikken said or, for PHP < 5.3.6, just use a regular expression:

```
$html = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $dom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` wasn't working in my environment. Alix's answer was the right way to solve this issue.