# How to make a link in a mysql stored variable clickable when rendered on the page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that enables members on a site to message each other; the message is stored in mysql database.

My question now is this: what is the best way to allow members to include a link in the message so that, when rendered, it is rendered as a click-able link.

I've tried the following:

```
<a href="testpage.html"> click here</a>
```

but when I then tried to render it on the page it came out as:

```
$message = nl2br($this->escapeHtml(trim($this->theMessage[0]['message'])));
echo $message;  // <a href="testpage.html"> click here</a>
```

the **var_dump** Values of **$messages** is:

```
string '&lt;a href=&quot;testpage.html&quot;&gt; click here&lt;/a&gt;'
```

Comment: Please attach a var_dump($this->theMessage[0]['message']) as example content.

Comment: hello Jens-andre Koch. thank you for quick response, i have edited my question and included the var_dumped values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML markup is complicated, because when displaying it to the user and someone has injected unsavory HTML into the markup, then you've got an XSS attack on your hands. Imagine an added onclick interception, etc.. Any data from outside is dangerous.

**markup language**

This is one of the reasons, why markup languages like BBCode and markdown exist.
You don't want every piece of HTML markup, only clean and safe stuff.
Basically, you want to work with a restricted set of "content".
And one way of allowing data from outside is by using an "intermediate" markup language.
It is intermediate, because it is a custom format, which is later transformed into HTML.

This happens here on Stackoverflow, too:
`[link](http://google.com)` = [link](http://google.com)

- tell your users: "to insert a link, using a special syntax"
- save the content to the database.
- the content you store to the database is something like:

`The message text. And some markdown [link](http://google.com)`.

- when you fetch the message from database, you process the markdown content:

  ```
  $messageFromDb = 'The message. [http://google.com](google)';

  $parsedown = new Parsedown();
  $html = $parsedown->text($messageFromDb); 

  echo $html; // ready to show
  ```
- Result: `<p>The message. <a href="google"><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></a></p>`

There are libraries out there ready for usage, like

- http://parsedown.org/
- https://github.com/egil/php-markdown-extra-extended

**filter html**

Another way is to allow HTML, but only an restricted set. You would have to filter the inserted HTML, to pick only the good content and drop the rest.

- PHP Extension Tidy: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php
- Libraries like http://htmlpurifier.org/

**DOM based HTML filter**

Instead of relying on a filter library, you could also come up with a "little" DOM based HTML filter.
The following example re-creates a clean link from a crappy and bad one.
You should also check the URL attributes to ensure they use known-good schemes like http:, and not troublesome like javascript:. 
This allows to whitelist the combination of elements, to control the nesting and the content.

```
<?php

// content from form
$html = 'Message <a href="http://google.com" onClick="alert(\'Hello World!\')"><img title="The Link" /> Link Text</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOXMLDECL);

// filter, then rebuild a clean link
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
    // extract the values
    $title = $node->nodeValue;
    $href = $node->getAttribute('href');

    // maybe add a href filter?
    // to remove links to bad websites
    // and to remove href="javascript:"
    // oh boy ... simple questions, resulting in lots of work ;)

    // create a new "clean" link element
    $link = $dom->createElement('a', $title);
    $link->setAttribute('href', $href);

    // replace old node
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $node);
}

$html = $dom->saveXML();

// drop html, body, get only html fragment
// http://stackoverflow.com/q/11216726/1163786
$html = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|body|p))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $dom->saveHTML());

var_dump($html);
```

**Before**

`Message <a href="http://google.com" onClick="alert(\'Hello World!\')"><img src="injectionHell.png" title="The Link" /> Link Text</a>`

**After**

`Message <a href="http://google.com"> Link Text</a>`

**To store "HTML in database"**

- When storing: use addslashes().
- When returning text from DB: apply stripslashes(), before rending

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to attain your goal is to save the message including the `<a>` tags.

You can use an HTML sanitizer so that you accept `<a>` link tags from your users while removing any potentially dangerous tags.

Then you wouldn't escape the saved text when you output it.

Have a look at [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Alternatively, you could use a Markdown parser to convert plain text to HTML.

Comment: Even if you would use `strip_tags($value, 'a')` You could still attach javascript to the tag to redirect a user to a malware invested site.

Comment: `strip_tags` should not be used for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

your code removes the html tags and replace it with a written form ...

```
escapeHtml()
```

what you need is a function that remove all your html tags except what you desire in this case (link tag)

```
<a>
```

here is the function you can add it to your code :

```
function stripme($msg){    

$msg = strip_tags($msg,'<a>'); 

return $msg ;    

}
```

and then call it for your message like this:

```
$message = nl2br($this->stripme($this->theMessage[0]['message']));
```