# Modify html attribute with php

Tags: php, dom

I have a html string that contains exactly one a-element in it. Example:

```
   <a href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow external">test</a>
```

In php I have to test if *rel* contains *external* and if yes, then modify *href* and save the string.

I have looked for DOM nodes and objects. But they seem to be too much for only one A-element, as I have to iterate to get html nodes and I am not sure how to test if *rel* exists and contains *external*.

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHtml($txt);
$a = $html->getElementsByTagName('a');
$attr = $a->item(0)->attributes();
...
```

At this point I am going to get NodeMapList that seems to be overhead. Is there any simplier way for this or should I do it with DOM?

Comment: When dealing with DOM you have two options: 1) use native DOM parser 2) Use regular expression (which is overhead)

Comment: Keep going. Use `DOMDocument()` for manipulation

Comment: Nobody should use the raw DOM methods for manipulation. Consider phpQuery or QueryPath etc. to reduce tedious boilerplate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there any simplier way for this or should I do it with DOM?

Do it with DOM.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$html = '<a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow external">test</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//a[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@rel), ' '), ' external ')]");
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('href', 'http://example.org');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: $dom->saveHTML(); 
This method, as of 5.2.6, will automatically add <html><body> and <!DOCTYPE> tags to the document if they are missing, without asking whether you want them.

Comment: Some query explanation would be beneficial to researchers.

Comment: @MarcinJaworski Thanks for the heads up – looks like the fix is to pass some flags to `loadHtml`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper

Answer (score 2):

I kept going to modify with DOM. This is what I get:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $txt);
$nodes = $html->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    foreach ($node->attributes as $att) {
        if ($att->name == 'rel') {
            if (strpos($att->value, 'external')) {
                $node->setAttribute('href','modified_url_goes_here');
            }
        }
    }
}
$txt = $html->saveHTML();
```

I did not want to load any other library for just this one string.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a HTML parser/DOM, but here's a regex solution:

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow external">test</a><br>
<p> Some text</p>
<a href="http://test.com">test2</a><br>
<a rel="external">test3</a> <-- This won\'t work since there is no href in it.
';

$new = preg_replace_callback('/<a.+?rel\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"[^>]*>/i', function($m){
    if(strpos($m[1], 'external') !== false){
        $m[0] = preg_replace('/href\s*=\s*(("[^"]*")|(\'[^\']*\'))/i', 'href="http://example.com"', $m[0]);
    }
    return $m[0];
}, $html);

echo $new;
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aeygFA).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like 
`if it matches /\s+rel\s*=\s*".*external.*"/` 
then do a regExp replace like 
`/(<a.*href\s*=\s*")([^"]\)("[^>]*>)/\1[your new href here]\3/`

Though using a library that can do this kind of stuff for you is much easier (like jquery for javascript)