# PHPDOM: how to edit style in HTML element

Tags: php, html, dom

I recently discovered PHPDom and found it very useful to manipulate HTML code. Unfortunately the documentation online is limited and there are no comprehensive PHPDom manuals that I am aware of. (There is no PHPdom tag in stockoverflow either!!)

This is the problem I am experiencing.

I would like to change the style an html tag, this is what I am using:

```
            $item = $dom->getElementById($name);
            $item->setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#FF0000;');
            $item = $dom->getElementById($name.'_error');
            $item->setAttribute('style', 'display:true;');
```

However the result of this code is that the styles defined in `$name` and `name.'_error'` are overwritten.

To fix the problem, I am looking for a PHPdom method, something like editAttribute, that allows to edit an attribute without overwriting the existing style attributes for that element.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Better check this question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127142/modify-html-attribute-with-php

Comment: That does not help as . In fact, Linda needs to replace the href as a whole, which is not my case.

Comment: I found the solution: `$item->setAttribute('style', $item->getAttribute('style') . 'background-color:#FF0000;');`@Sundar

Answer (score 0):

That would mean that you need to parse and edit the CSS properties in the attribute.

I implemented that in [FluentDOM](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM), actually. You can do something like:

```
$fd = FluentDOM($html, 'text/html');
$fd
  ->find('//a')
  ->css['text-decoration'] = 'none';
echo (string)$fd;
```

This logic is located in `FluentDOM\Query\Css\Properties`. You can use this object to edit a style property string.

```
$style = new FluentDOM\Query\Css\Properties($node->getAttribute('style'));
$style['background-color'] = '#FF0000';
$node->setAttribute('style', $style);
```