# How to remove attributes html and replace an another attributes?

Tags: php, html

I have a string like this:

`<p>title="abc" </p>
<p title="a"><a title="b"></a></p><pre title="c"></pre>`

I want to replace string `title` is `class` inside html tag and keep string 'title' outside html tag. Please tell me if you have any ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: You could use PHP's DOM implementation, specifically the [Document Fragment](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php) part. Parse it into DOM, manipulate it, then serialise it back into HTML.

Comment: So may you give me some demo?, i'm a new guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with PHP, you should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Maybe this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127142/modify-html-attribute-with-php) can help you.

edit : sorry for the linked-only answer. Here is a example of code :

```
$html = '<p>title="abc" </p><p title="a"><a title="b"></a></p><pre title="c"></pre>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->getAttribute('title')) {
        $node->setAttribute('class', $node->getAttribute('title'));
        $node->removeAttribute('title');
    }
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

This code will give you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>title="abc" </p><p class="a"><a class="b"></a></p><pre class="c"></pre></body></html>
```

You can then remove header + extra tags (html/body) if you don't need it. 
[Online example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a9a34a5963f6c65f80834e716a8641ab077d203)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: So may you give me some demo?, i'm a new guy

Comment: I've edited my answer, sorry guys. :)

Comment: No problem, thanks you so much neodem. It's work.:)