# What Wordpress hook can I use to filter content output to the browser if I'm using an Elementor template to render the page?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor on a site and an Elementor template page containing the [Social Icons widget](https://elementor.com/help/social-icons-widget/).  Since this is a template, the social icon's URL is dynamic and pulls data from and ACF field.

I'm trying to display or hide each social icon based on whether or not a URL for the respective social icon exists in the database.

I already implemented a "hack" to filter the final rendered HTML output following ideas from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127142).  However, I'm trying to do this without having to use the PHP DOM methods as they don't support HTML5 and converting back and forth from HTML5 causes some issues on our site.  In addition the DOM methods require parsing the entire page's HTML output which we don't need.

Ideally I'd like to find a hook that could filter ONLY the social icons widget's HTML output, before the HTML output is actually created.  Possibly where Wordpress is gathering the data to render the page.

I'm aware of the Elementor hook's for the [front-end](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/render-frontend-elements/) and [widgets](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/render-widget-content/) but I'm not sure if these hooks are implemented in the proper proper page-rendering life cycle stage or if there is method I can use to run the checks and modify output.  The widget hooks seem to apply to the Elementor theme editor display, as opposed to the actual page pre-rendering.