# Set PHP DOM to not correct html when <html>,<head>,<body> tags are not set

Tags: php, html, dom

He I have made this function to set attributes on id:

```
function set_atr($id, $attribute, $value, $source){

    $dom = new DomDocument();

    $dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'.$source);

    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $element = $xp->query('//*[@id="'.$id.'"]')->item(0);

    if(!$element){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $element->setAttribute($attribute, $value);
        return str_replace('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">', '', $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
    }
}
```

When I don't use this to edit the entire document but just a snap of it like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <td><h4>login</h4></td>
            <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>username:</td>
        <td>password:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="pipo" name="username" class="form" /></td>
        <td><input id="password" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" name="password" class="form" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="error1"></td>
        <td id="error2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Login" class="btn" action="url" level="cms_user_login" form="login" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

it assumes that the rest of the document is missing and it adds the additional html tags like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>    <table>
    <tr>
            <td><h4>login</h4></td>
            <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>username:</td>
        <td>password:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="pipo" name="username" class="form" /></td>
        <td><input id="password" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" name="password" class="form" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="error1"></td>
        <td id="error2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Login" class="btn" action="url" level="cms_user_login" form="login" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table></body>
</html>
```

It does not hurt directly but it looks ugly. The reason I use it this way is because I use ajax a lot and I only send back a snippet of the html not a whole document.

So anyone knows how to make DOM stop doing this? Or is this impossible. I can also just use str_replace to delete them when I use my function but I consider that a ugly fix.

Comment: Check out this question it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/domdocument-savehtml-without-html-wrapper

Comment: Ah yes it looks intresting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `<meta>` tag will trigger the fixing behavior of `DOMDocument`. The good part is that you don't need to add that tag at all. If you wan't to use an encoding of your choosing just pass it as a constructor argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$node = $doc->createElement('div', 'Hello World');
$doc->appendChild($node);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Libxml >= 2.7.7 (as of PHP >= 5.4.0) call `loadHTML` with `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` as the second argument. E.g.

```
$dom->loadHTML($source, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
```

This will suppress the addition of the implied `<html>` and `<body>` elements.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/4016256) answer.