# Why is php DOM treating elements differently between machines?

Tags: php, domdocument

With this code:

```
<?php
    $s = '<h1>Header</h1>';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($s, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    var_dump($dom->documentElement->childNodes->item(0));
?>
```

On my development machine,the `var_dump` spits out a `DOMText` object, yet on my production machine it's returning a `DOMElement` object.

Production server is running `php 5.4.33` with `libxml 2.7.8`

Dev machine is running `php 5.4.4` with `libxml 2.8.0`

Comment: Do you have the same versions of libxml and php installed on both machines?

Comment: No, I will add the versions to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably got something to do with different PHP versions:
The `DOMDocument::loadHTML` method only accepted a second (`$options`) argument since PHP 5.4, it's listed on [the changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/doc.changelog.php):

> 5.4.0 DOMDocument::loadHTML   Added options parameter.
>       DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile   Added options parameter.

The changes are also listed [on the `DOMDocument::loadHTML` doc pages](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Update:

After some digging, I found a lot of contradictory information concerning the `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` constant. according to the docs, it's available in >= libxml 2.7.7, whereas other sources contradict this. I have found some projects that define this constant manually, and [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/1230836) that states that this constant is *only* available in libxml 2.7.8.
This could explain the difference between your 2 environments. [An open-source project on github](https://github.com/yangweijie/SublimeThinkPHP/blob/master/phpruntime/libxml.php) tackles this issue by simply defining the constant if needed:

```
defined('LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD') || define ('LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD', 4);
```

Comment: Sorry - added the versions to my question, both machines are running php 5.4

Comment: You are correct though, as saveHTML() on my server spits out `<html><body><h1>Header</h1></body></html>`, so it is obviously ignoring the options argument...

Comment: @danbroooks: I'm scanning through a couple of bug reports, and the libxml changelogs now. There have been people reporting similar behavior to that which you seem to encounter... using xpaths is the common workaround ATM, though

Comment: @danbroooks: added some findings after a quick google sessions

Comment: Thanks for doing some digging for me! However defining the constant doesn't seem to do much, and looking at the values of the constants between machines show they both hold the same values (4 & 8192).

Comment: To be honest it looks like `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` is the argument that is refusing to work... with `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` removed the doctype is added as you would expect.