# Why does DOMDocument nest paragraph (<p>) tags?

Tags: php, domdocument

Is there any way to prevent DOMDocument from nesting

tags? Here's an example:

```
$dom->loadHTML('<p>text1</p><p>text2</p>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Outputs:

```
<p>text1<p>text2</p></p>
```

Any advice? That seems really strange.

Comment: Answered my own question. It seems it's the LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED option that does this. I'll need to find another way to remove the html and body tags from being output.

Comment: I left an answer to this on a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29499718/367456 - It's a reworded variant from http://stackoverflow.com/a/29499398/367456