# Stray end tag </source> with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, domdocument

I am using PHP 7.1 and found an error with DOMDocument lib. The code is

```
$body = '<figure>'
        . '<picture>'
            . '<source srcset="img.webp 100vw" type="image/webp">'
            . '<img src="img.jpg" alt="">'
        . '</picture>'
        . '</figure>';

$dom = new \DOMDocument();
if (@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($body, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD))
    return $dom->saveHTML((new \DOMXPath($dom))->query('/')->item(0));
```

Return result is

```
<figure>
    <picture>
        <source srcset="img.webp 100vw" type="image/webp">
            <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
        </source>
    </picture>
</figure>
```

As you can see, DOMDocument adds `</source>` to close tag. But this is an error. How to fix it?

p.s. I also used this loadHTML trick, but it does not help: 
[loadHTML LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED on an html fragment generates incorrect tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493678/loadhtml-libxml-html-noimplied-on-an-html-fragment-generates-incorrect-tags)

Comment: Its fixing it, your trying to use something for HTML and output xml structure, why not use XML lib?

Comment: Can you provide example please?

Comment: It seems it is a know bug, you could try for example the `html5-dom-document-php` class instead, see https://ivopetkov.com/b/a-better-html5-parser-for-php/. Or manually remove all `</source>` tags.

Comment: It's a known (well, reported) issue in PHP from two years ago and is as yet unresolved. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73175. Ultimately, DOMDocument is not remotely in sync with the current state of HTML. A third party library as above is definitely a better option.

Comment: Still not working on php 7.3.4 :@

Comment: A solution is finally in sight. 
In PHP 8.4 there will be an HTML5 parser: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/domdocument_html5_parser


Until then ivopetkov.com/b/a-better-html5-parser-for-php works pretty well.