# php DOMDocument: element ending up within another

Tags: php, domdocument

I have some HTML that contains (among other things) `p`-tags and `figure`-tags that contain one `img`-tag.
For the sake of simplicity I'll define an example of what can be found in the HTML here in a PHP variable:

```
$content = '<figure class="image image-style-align-left">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></figure>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>';
```

I use DOMDocument to get `$content` and in this example I'll change the `src` attribute of all `img`-elements within a `figure`-element:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// this needs to be encoded otherwise special characters get messed up.
$domPart = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
$dom->loadHTML($domPart, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$domFigures = $dom->getElementsByTagName('figure');

foreach ($domFigures as $domFigure) {

    $img = $domFigure->getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    if ($img) {
        $img->setAttribute('src', "https://placekitten.com/g/400/500");
    }

}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

The result is:

```
<figure class="image image-style-align-left">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/500">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
</figure>
```

Somehow my `p`-element has moved into my `figure`-element. **Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?**

[Live DEMO](https://3v4l.org/AgIjB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DomDocument` has to have a single root element, so it will move all following siblings inside the first top-level element.

You could most easily address this by bookending your content with a container tag e.g.

```
$content = '<div><figure class="image image-style-align-left">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></figure>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The re-arrangement is done by the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` option you're using. Looks like it's not stable enough for your case.

Look at this answer : [loadHTML LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED on an html fragment generates incorrect tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493678/loadhtml-libxml-html-noimplied-on-an-html-fragment-generates-incorrect-tags)
And
[How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper)

**Note** : PHP 5.4 and Libxml 2.6  loadHTML now has a $option parameter which instructs Libxml about how it should parse the content.