# DOMDocument expands first tag

Tags: php, domdocument

<strike>I am trying to add attributes to document nodes with DOMDocument.</strike> *This is not part of the problem.*
Unfortunately, the first tag in my html is expanded to span the entire document.

The problem can be seen in this example:

```php
<?php

$html = "<h3>HEADING</h3><p>&nbsp;</p><p>lorem ipsum</p>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();

// prevent warning and errors when loading html 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// load html, convert to utf-8, prevent appending "<html>" headers
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    
var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

(Interactive here: https://3v4l.org/ddQZ9)

This code generates this output:

```
string(48) "<h3>HEADING<p>&nbsp;</p><p>lorem ipsum</p></h3>"
```

which is not what I intended, since the `<h3>` tag now spans all the html.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: What attribute are you trying to add and to which tag?

Comment: @nice_dev Sorry about the confusion, adding attributes is not part of the problem. The problem is the expanded tag.

Comment: You are trying to load something which isn't a valid HTML document.  It is expecting the string to have a single node with contents, if you add a `<div>` tag (for example) round the current content, you should get the right output.

Comment: `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` is causing the issue, why are you using it? [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36547335/5897602) - wrap it all in a [`<html></html>`](https://3v4l.org/2vM0s) to fix.