# Find <p> that contains image(s) and change style of that <p>

Tags: php, dom

I'm parsing Wordpress post HTML through PHP. I want all images to be centered. This alone is easy enough, however, I also want images on the same line to be centered together. In order to do this I need to apply the attribute `class="image-content"` to the `<p>` block.

How do I do this with PHP?

This is what the post would look like in the editor:

[image]

And this is the HTML that Wordpress provides for this post:

```
<p>Single line paragraph.</p>
<p>
    <a href="image.png">
        <img class="alignnone wp-image-39 size-thumbnail" src="image.png" width="150" height="150" />
    </a>
</p>
<p>
    Multi line paragraph which is a multi line paragraph 
    which is a multi line paragraph which is a multi line 
    paragraph which is a multi line paragraph which is a 
    multi line paragraph which is a multi line paragraph 
    which is a multi line paragraph which is a multi line
     paragraph which is a multi line paragraph which is a 
     multi line paragraph which is a multi line paragraph 
     which is a multi line paragraph which is a multi line 
     paragraph which is a multi line paragraph which is a 
     multi line paragraph which is a multi line paragraph.
</p>
<p>
    <a href="image.png">
        <img class="alignnone wp-image-39 size-thumbnail" src="image.png" width="150" height="150" />
    </a>
    <a href="image.png">
        <img class="alignnone wp-image-39 size-thumbnail" src="image.png" width="300" height="300" />
    </a>
</p>
<p>End of post.</p>
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the content?

Comment: Since you've already tagged your question with the *dom* tag: What have you already tried? Did you try out any of the PHP DOM libraries?

Comment: I'm not *currently* doing anything, I originally tried to use DOM to look at every `<p>` block, detect the content and apply an appropriate style but I couldn't work it out. I assumed this would use DOM which is why I tagged it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with DOMDocument, xpath and a simple replacement.

```
    $parse = new \DOMDocument();
    $parse->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new \DOMXpath($parse);
    $images = $xpath->query('//p//img');

    $re = "/(.*)/";
    $subst = "$1 image-content";

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $class = preg_replace($re, $subst, $image->getAttribute('class'), 1);
        $image->setAttribute('class',$class);
    }

    $htmlFinal = $parse->saveHTML();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to attach the class to the containing `p` Element, you can use it like this:

```
    $parse = new \DOMDocument();
    $parse->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new \DOMXpath($parse);
    $ps = $xpath->query('//p');

    foreach ($ps as $p) {
        if ($p->getElementsByTagName('img')->length > 0) $p->setAttribute('class', 'image-content');           
    }

    $htmlFinal = $parse->saveHTML();
```

If the `p` tags may have a class set before parsing the Dom, you should combine those two examples to add the new class instead of only setting it.

Comment: There won't always be links attached to the images, is that going to be a problem?

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer, no it will find all images within a `p` tag

Comment: @Joe I have edited my anser to add a solution which will attach the class to the containing `p` element

Comment: Hey, thanks. This *sort-of* worked. `saveHTML()` seems to wrap the HTML in `<html>` and `<body>` tags, as well as a doctype. I had to do `    $parse->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` to have it not include those, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper Was that intended in your answer?

Comment: Also, `class="image-content"` is being set on the first `<p>` of every post, any idea why that's happening?This is the current code: http://pastebin.com/5i2yhiDp

Comment: Ok this is very strange, the first <p> element seems to register as containing **all** images in the post!