# PHP Regex - How to append to a URL (in a string variable with a lot of text) where there is an <a href>

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am working on an automation for building Landingpages.

A copy/pastes from a word doc to a TinyMCE textarea which creates the  in the output.

so if I copy/paste something like this:

> This is my [Website](http://www.google.com).

from a word doc - the output of it after sending the form will look like this:

```
This is my <a href="http://www.google.com">Website</a>.
```

I want to append to every link within an `<a href>` tag (**only within an `<a href>` tag!**) something like this:

> ?utm=foo_foo_foo

so it will look like this:

```
This is my <a href="http://www.google.com?utm=foo_foo_foo">Website</a>.
```

P.S: urls can end with "/" or without, this shouldn't matter, but should work both ways.

P.S2: TinyMCR adds the  tags by itself (if you haven't noticed me mentioning it..,). I just need to append to a string that looks like this:

```
$string = "This is my <a href="http://www.google.com">Website</a>.";
```

Comment: any code? have you tried anything? Moreover, please, let us know that either you're generating these `href` and yielding page OR you've page and want to change all `anchor` tags?

Comment: No code, I went through regex and preg_replace tutorials, everything is basic and not accurate to my needs.

and I'm not sure I understand your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a parser, not a regex for this.

```
$html = 'This is my <a href="http://www.google.com">Website</a>.';
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $link) {
    $link->setAttribute('href', $link->getAttribute('href') . '?utm=foo_foo_foo');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>This is my <a href="http://www.google.com?utm=foo_foo_foo">Website</a>.</p></body></html>
```

If you had to use a regex you could do

```
$html = 'This is my <a href="http://www.google.com">Website</a>.';
echo preg_replace('~href=("|\')(.+?)\1~', 'href=$1$2?utm=foo_foo_foo$1', $html);
```

Output:

```
This is my <a href="http://www.google.com?utm=foo_foo_foo">Website</a>.
```

Both these approaches presume you never have a `?` in the URL already..

Comment: Oooh. ok. I'm new to PHP, Can you give me a short explanation before I try it and start exploring "parers" ? 

Just guessing, Parsers pars texts/variables... so what difference them from regex? From what I know "Regex" searches for a pattern in a text and can change/add stuff to it.

Comment: I am free to use whatever I want in this code, tell me what you think is better and why, anyway I'm gonna continue researching both now. 

Learning everyday something new B|.

Comment: There's a longer write up on parsers here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php. Parsers are cleaner and have predefined functions, also if a failure occurs with a parser it won't destroy, with regex you have possibility to go very wrong.

Comment: Yes, the parsers code looks more organized to be honest.. 
Thanks, I'll try this in a second and update you if it's working right.

Comment: Also removing HTML declaration with parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper.

Comment: Hi! 
I now noticed, that when posting the texts to the new PHP file, I get the text surounded with: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>abc</p></body></html>`, any idea how to remove this?

Comment: See my previous last comment.

Comment: Tnx, I'll take a look.