# Replace and return partial HTML with DOMDocument without adding body, doctype, etc

Tags: php, html, laravel, domdocument

I want to operate some replacement on a partial document HTML document. Let's say, I want to add something on the `src` argument of `img` tags.

(Example) Replace:

```
<p>hello</p><img src="REPLACE" /><p></p>
```

By:

```
<p>hello</p><img src="http://example.org/image.jpeg" /><p></p>
```

I did want to use DOMDocument to achieve this, so I coded something like this:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->loadHTML('<p>hello</p><img src="REPLACE" /><p></p>');
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag->setAttribute('src', 'http://example.org/image.jpeg');
}
var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

But it returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
    <p>hello</p><img src="http://example.org/image.jpeg"><p></p>
</body></html>
```

There are several problems with this return:

- It uses a strange doctype: `HTML 4.0`!
- It did add a doctype, a html tag and a body tag.

I know it's "normal" that DOMDocument add doctype, html and body tag, but **can I avoid this**? Is there anyway to "just" recover my HTML slice, with only the replacement I performed? Using regex is not an option, because there post everywhere saying it's bad practice.

*Side note: I use Laravel, so if there is something out of the box for Laravel, it could be great too!*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use extra options available in [loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to achieve what you want. Check the `options` parameter. Detail about the libxml constants [here](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php). And note that its available since PHP 5.4. Like:

```
...
$doc->loadHTML('<p>hello</p><img src="REPLACE" /><p></p>',
    LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | 
    LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
...
$doc->saveHTML();
```

### *Update*

If you see UTF-8 characters being changed to some odd characters, then using [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) can fix this, like:

```
$doc->loadHTML(
    mb_convert_encoding('<p>hello</p><img src="REPLACE" /><p></p>', 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), 
    LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | 
    LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD 
);
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Still it brokes my utf8 by replacing it by some Ã© chars. Is there an option for that too? (sorry it was not in the OP)

Comment: @rap-2-h you coud try like:: $doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding('<p>hello</p><img src="REPLACE" /><p></p>', 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use laravel option then you can just call the partial that you have and have it return the html for you:

```
$src = "http://example.org/image.jpeg"
return view('path_to_partial', compact('src'))->render();
```