# PHP DOM function adding an extra <p> <html> and a <body> tags

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I use the following function to show a different image to desktop and mobile user depending on their device.

**My index.php file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
define("DEVICE", "desktop");
ob_start(); 
?>
<?php echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' . '<br/>'?> 
<?php echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' . '<br/>'?> 
<?php echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' . '<br/>'?> 
<?php echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' . '<br/>'?> 
<?php echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' . '<br/>'?> 
<?php echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' . '<br/>'?> 
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<img src="/desktop-img/blog-1.png" alt="blog-1">
<img src="/desktop-img/blog-2.png" alt="blog-2">
<img src="/desktop-img/blog-3.png" alt="blog-3">
</div>
<?php
// Assign bufferred content to a variable for further processing
$content = ob_get_clean();

// Device specific images
function selectPaths($tag){

    // If paths is wrapped in <pre> or <code> tags
    if($tag->nodeName=="pre" || $tag->nodeName=="code"){
        return;
    // If not wrapped witihn <pre> or <code> tags
    } elseif($tag->nodeName=="img"){
        // Replace device specific path
        $tag->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->nodeValue=str_replace('desktop-img', DEVICE . '-img',$tag->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->nodeValue);
    } elseif($tag->hasChildNodes()){
        foreach($tag->childNodes as $child){
            selectPaths($child);
        }
    }
}

function deviceImages($content){

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $root=$dom->documentElement;
    selectPaths($root);
    $dom->formatOutput=false;
    //Assign to variable
    $content = $dom->saveHTML($root);
    return $content;
}
$content = deviceImages ($content);
?>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My challenge:**

This function is adding a `<p>` tag and also and extra `<html><body>` tags to my output.

**My output image**
[image]

**My output Source code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <html><body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br></p>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<img src="/desktop-img/blog-1.png" alt="blog-1"><img src="/desktop-img/blog-2.png" alt="blog-2"><img src="/desktop-img/blog-3.png" alt="blog-3">
</div>
</body></html></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My output source code image**

[image]

**My question:**

How can I avoid this `<p>` `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

**UPDATED**

Updated as per the suggestion of @Aknosis about the `<br/>` tags.

Comment: I have no answer for your first question, but it's stripping the `</br>` tags because they're invalid HTML. They should be `<br/>` tags.

Comment: @Aknosis Thanks for the suggestion. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content you output is generated via DOMDocument's saveHTML method:

```
$content = $dom->saveHTML($root);
```

You reference the root node here, which is the documentElement which then is the parent element of that `<html>` element you do not want to output. So choose the correct element to output, e.g. the body of that document.

```
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$content = implode(
    "",
    array_map([$doc, 'saveHTML'], iterator_to_array($body->childNodes))
);

echo $content;
```

In your case, I think instead of the `<body>` element you take the first `<p>` element.

For some related cases, a different approach might be necessary, there is also additional Q&A material here on site for that topic:

- [How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2087103/367456)
- [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4879946/367456)

Comment: Not saying I would do that for payment for you, but this site is about learning, not about getting things done by others.

Comment: Replace `$doc` with `$dom`, you're using a different variable name for the DOM-document (or I'm using a different one in my example than in your question, my fault).

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I was running the example on PHP 7.1, maybe a copy/paste error?

Comment: My PHP version is 5.6.31. I use Dreamweaver CS6 for coding and it is showing a syntax error in this `$content = implode( "", array_map([$dom, 'saveHTML'], iterator_to_array($body->childNodes)));` Kindly check as I mentioned, I am not an expert in coding.

Comment: Some different syntax might work for your then: `$content = ""; foreach($body->childNodes as $node) $content .= $dom->saveHTML($node);`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `DOMDocument` always needs a root tag, so if you put raw text without any parent HTML tag, `DOMDocument` will add it implicitly (so `some text` becomes `<p>some text</p>`). The best I could think of is to add root tags explicitly and the remove them from `saveHTML()` result:

```
$dom->loadHTML(
    '<html><body>' . $html . '</body></html>',
    LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED
);

// do your stuff

$result = str_replace(['<html><body>', '</body></html>'], '', $dom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: I added LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED but still see <p> tag being randomly added to a few places in the output