# Ignore a specific tag in regex - negitive lookahead

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

So, I have this scenario in my `php` code where I have the following string

```
This is an outside Example <p href="https://example.com"> This is a para Example</p><markup class="m"> this is a markup example</markup>
```

And I want to do a case-insensitive search for the word `example` in this string, but

- I want my regex to ignore occurrence of example inside a tag attribute (which I am able to achieve)
- I want to ignore search inside the following `<markup ..> any content </markup>` entirely

What I have done till now is,

`/(example)(?:[^<]*>)/i`

This works fine and ignores the example within `href` of `p` tag, 
now I have modified it for the `<markup>`

`/(example)(?!([^<]*>)|(\<markup[^>]*>[^<]*<\/markup\>))/i`

but this isn't working.
you can see my work - https://regex101.com/r/e2XujN/1

> **What I want to achieve with this**

I will be replacing the matched `example` word, in the following way

- Suppose if i found `eXamPle` it will be replace by `<markup>eXamPle</markup>`
- `Example` will be replace by `<markup>Example</markup>`

and so on,

> Note: Case of the pattern in the matched string and replace string is same

Comment: Can you give me an example of how this can be achieved using DOM @ php.

Comment: Are you trying to replace matched sub-string with sth or it's just a matter of knowing number of occurrences?

Comment: I want to do a case-insensitive search for the word `example` 
and i'll be replacing the matched `eXample` with `<markup>eXample</markup>`. 

note: case in replace string is same  as matched string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(*SKIP)(*F)` predicated in PCRE to match and skip certain substrings enclosed by a pattern/string (here *markup*) like this:

[`(markup).*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|(example)(?![^<]*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/y1j5t6/1)

Explanation:

Excluded Substring: 1st Capturing Group
 (markup): matches the characters markup literally (case insensitive)
 `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
`\1` matches the same text as the 1st capturing group
`(*SKIP)` over
`(*F)` shorthand for (*FAIL), do not match

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got to learning something new. Really saved my day

Comment: Welcome. In hindsight, I would use a more closed & lazy pattern like this: [`<markup.*?<\/markup>(*SKIP)(*F)|(example)(?![^<]*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/y1j5t6/2) Maybe just an edge case but if you have a long test sitting on a single line it would matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it the same way you did with the first problem. Check if the string is not directly followed by a closing tag.

**Regex:**

`(example)(?![^<]*>)(?![^<]*<\/markup\>)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HudqZ3/1)

Comment: I like that, but it fails if there are more tags in the <markup>-substring: https://regex101.com/r/AH5EQx/1

Comment: Yes, this definitely solves my problem but @wp78de is right. His solution is more foolproof. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using DOM, however it's a little tricky to work with text nodes and inserting HTML content into them.

**[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/2CBun)**

```
$content = <<< 'HTML'
This is an outside Example <p href="https://example.com"> This is a para Example</p>
test <markup class="m"> this is a markup example</markup> another example <p>example</p>
HTML;

// Initialize a DOM object
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// Use an HTML element tag as our HTML container
// @hakre [https://stackoverflow.com/a/29499718/1020526]
@$dom->loadHTML("<div>$content</div>");

$wrapper = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
// Remove wrapper
$wrapper = $wrapper->parentNode->removeChild($wrapper);
// Remove all nodes of $dom object
while ($dom->firstChild) {
    $dom->removeChild($dom->firstChild);
}
// Append all $wrapper object nodes to $dom
while ($wrapper->firstChild) {
    $dom->appendChild($wrapper->firstChild);
}

$dox = new DOMXPath($dom);
// Query all elements in addition to text nodes
$query = $dox->query('/* | /text()');

// Iterate through all nodes
foreach ($query as $node) {
    // If it's not an HTML element
    if ($node->nodeType != XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        // Replace desired word / content
        $newContent = preg_replace('~(example)~i',
            '<markup>$1</markup>',
            $node->wholeText);
        // We can't insert HTML directly into our node
        // so we need to create a document fragment
        $newNode = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
        $newNode->appendXML($newContent);
        // Replace new content with old one
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
    }
}

// Save modifications
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom);
```

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. but this also skips `example` inside <p> tag.  it should only be skipping the example inside <markup> tag. So the expected output for your example should be



`This is an outside <markup>Example</markup> <p href="https://example.com"> This is a para  <markup>Example</markup></p> test <markup class="m"> this is a markup example</markup> another <markup>example</markup> <p><markup>example</markup></p>`