# How to retrieve string of resulting DOM markup after xpath and DOM operations (PHP)?

Tags: php, xpath

I am modifying a form element. I have a function that is passed some HTML corresponding to the form (a `div` with form elements).

I modify the form as

```
function modify_form($paypal_button, $payment_params) {
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML($paypal_button);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
    $itemno =  $xpath->query('//form[@name="buynow"]/input[@name="item_number"]');
    $itemno->item(0)->setAttribute('value', 'SomeNewVal');
    $itemname =  $xpath->query('//form[@name="buynow"]/input[@name="item_name"]');
    $itemname->item(0)->setAttribute('value', 'SomeNewTitle');
    paypal_button = $d->saveHTML();
    return paypal_button;
}
```

What I am trying to return is simply a string, same format as what I was passed. That is, my modified version of `$paypal_button`.

With above, a bunch of HTML opening and closing tags are added - such as

```
?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
```

Whereas I need the format to be untouched.

By the way, are XPath and DOM functions overkill for this? I mean, `$paypal_button` is not a lot of text by any means... That is an aside.  At this point, just trying to figure out how to retrieve the modified markup after I do the two node modifications.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are after, but it may be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for.