# Text from <p> tag using DOM Php

Tags: php, dom

Hey,
Consider i have the follwing html syntax

```
<p>xyz</p>
<p>abc</p>
```

I want to retrieve the text (xyz and abc) using DOM.

This is my code.

```
<?php
$link='http://www.xyz.com';
$ret= getLinks($link);
print_r ($ret);

function getLinks($link)
{
    /*** return array ***/
    $ret = array();

    /*** a new dom object ***/
    $dom = new domDocument;

    /*** get the HTML (suppress errors) ***/
    @$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($link));

    /*** remove silly white space ***/
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    /*** get the links from the HTML ***/
    $text = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

/*** loop over the links ***/
    foreach ($text as $tag)
    {
        $ret[] = $tag->innerHTML;
    }

    return $ret;
}
?>
```

But i get an empty result. wat am i miissing here.?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it yet? Try putting `die($variable);` after each statement and determine which one does not correctly work. Also, I think it's `DOMDocument` and I'm not sure there is an `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To suppress parsing errors, do **not** use

```
@$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($link));
```

but

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
```

Also, there is no reason to use `file_get_contents`. DOM can load from remote resources.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($link);
libxml_clear_errors();
```

Also, Tag Names are case sensitive. You are querying for `<P>` when the snippet contains `<p>`. Change to

```
$text = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

And finally, there is no `innerHTML`. A userland solution to fetch it is in

- [How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

You can fetch the `outerHTML` with

```
$ret[] = $dom->saveHtml($tag); // requires PHP 5.3.6+
```

or

```
$ret[] = $dom->saveXml($tag); // that will make it XML compliant though
```

To get the text content of the P tag, use

```
$ret[] = $tag->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, case matters:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('P');
```

Should be:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

Second, `innerHTML` is not a valid DOMElement property.

Try:

```
echo $dom->textContent;
echo $dom->nodeValue;
```

However, this won't return the inner HTML tags and will strip them. There are a [few examples on how to make it work in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#101243).