# php DOMDocument class: return node instance

Tags: php, html, class, domdocument

Using the DOMDocument class, I want to return the div elements as array items

```
 $str = '
 <div class="outer">outer div text
    <div class="inner">inner div text</div>
 </div>
 ';

 $document = new DOMDocument();
```

ex:

```
$item[0] = '<div class="outer">outer div text 
               <div class="inner">inner div text</div> 
           </div>'

$item[1] = '<div class="inner">inner div text</div>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text from <p> tag using DOM Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971373/text-from-p-tag-using-dom-php/4971426#4971426)

Comment: The content of the first div is $str and not $item[0].

Comment: @powtac: $str contains the whole html content, $item[0] contains only the outer div element.

Comment: Also see [Noob Question about DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721) for some more information on how DOM works.

Comment: @Gordon: I edited my question, my goal is to return all div instances in my html code.

Comment: @dany well, i take you know how to put stuff into an array. For the DOM part see both of the linked answers then. It's really just a matter of `getElementsByTagName` and `saveHTML` or `saveXML`. Like I said: Duplicate, hence Closevote :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [outerHTML for DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element/5404962#5404962)

Comment: @Gordon: I know I can return the inner-html of the div layers with the "nodeValue" property, isn't there just a "node" property to return the div layer as a whole?

Comment: @dany You are wrong. The nodeValue property will only get the DOMText nodes. It will not include any other elements, hence it's not innerHTML. [There is no innerHTML method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument). For the outerHTML see the various linked answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, not perfect code but it works.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$entries = ($doc->getElementsByTagName('div'));

foreach($entries as $data) {
    $divs[] = '<div>'.trim($data->nodeValue).'</div>';
}
```

Comment: there is methods for getting the outerHTML and your solution will not add the attributes, nor will it include the innerHTML. And why is the call to getElementsByTagName in brackets? This solution does not work!