# Fetching <p> tags using dom parser

Tags: php, dom, curl

I am using `curl` to fetch website content into a variable. Now, using either the 'url' or the fetched content i want to extract all the `<p>` tags into a variable. 
Can anyone guide me on this ?

After hours i have just been able to create a DOM Document in php !

This is the code i have written:

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc->loadHTML($content);

print_r($domDoc);

$paragraphs = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("p");
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph)
    $paragraph->item(0)->nodevalue;
```

where `$content` contains the website content fetched using

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url[url]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml_contents = curl_exec ($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close ($ch);
$website_content = $xml_contents;
```

Can someone please guide me ?

Comment: any error you getting ? in which part you want guidance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text from <p> tag using DOM Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971373/text-from-p-tag-using-dom-php)

Comment: I am getting this error.
DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity.

Comment: @Adithya: The HTML you load is that much invalid that even `DOMDocument::loadHTML` can't fix it (probably). At least you get the error. You can disable errors: [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) but if the document is broken too much, you need to fix it first, see [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

Comment: yeah..i got the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `item()` in the `foreach` loop. Simply access `nodeValue` directly from the `$paragraph` variable to get the content of the `p` tag.

You'll want to use `item()` only if you're using a normal `for` loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $paragraphs->length; $i++) 
{
    echo $paragraphs->item($i)->nodeValue;
}
```