# PHP Scrape html page content with tags

Tags: php, html, scrape

The code from original web page

```
<html>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="slider">
<ul>  
<li>
<a title="title1" href="http://www.link.com" >
<img  title="title1"  alt=""  src="http://www.link.com/1.jpg"  /></a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="title2" href="http://www.link.com" >
<img  title="title2"  alt=""  src="http://www.link.com/2.jpg"  /></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</html>
```

and I want to extract below details (with tags) same as below

```
<div class="slider">
<ul>  
<li>
<a title="title1" href="http://www.link.com" >
<img  title="title1"  alt=""  src="http://www.link.com/1.jpg"  /></a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="title2" href="http://www.link.com" >
<img  title="title2"  alt=""  src="http://www.link.com/2.jpg"  /></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Checked many questions posted before but I can't find something similar to this so Please someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this thing so I didn't do anything

Comment: So at least edit your question and add example output.

Comment: I have added the example output that i am looking

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get what you need to do, describe it carefully.

Comment: I needs to scrape some parts of web page including tags the first example shows the original code and 2nd example is showing which part i needs to extract

Comment: Jonny King, thank-you for the example, but in this case we actually need something more general too. Are you trying to grab all `div` tags with the `slider` class out of an HTML document?

Comment: geez guys, just close it and give the OP time to do some more research until he can come up with a concrete question. Its not like there wasnt a couple hundred similar questions on SO already.

Comment: no there is only div tag with slider on that page

Comment: @Gordon I did but i got a lot of answers with exclude html tags I am looking for including html tags.

Comment: You want the **outerHTML** of the div *element* with the class *attribute* slider. Search for outerHTML in DOMDocument please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument OuterHTML for Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOMDocument for parsing HTML instead of Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324620/domdocument-for-parsing-html-instead-of-regex/7325380#7325380)

Comment: @Gordon Thanks a lot my credits goes to you...I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate HTML it is better not to use regular expressions like `preg_replace`. Why? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You can use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) as HTML parser.

Install it with the following commands (you need pear):

```
pear channel-discover phpquery-pear.appspot.com  
pear install phpquery/phpQuery
```

After installing, you can do the following:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.your-url.com/");
$pq = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
echo $pq['.slider']; // Output the contents of tags with class="slider"
```

For more example code and **documentation**, please take at the **[phpQuery web page](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)**

**Edit:**

If you want to use another HTML parsing solution, you can take a look at [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: Since I am using shared hosting I am unable to install it on the server...Can you please figure it out how to extract it with including the html tags ?

Comment: You can use pear on shared hosting. Either via SSH or via FTP. Take a look at this: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

Comment: Thanks a lot got it worked with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324620/domdocument-for-parsing-html-instead-of-regex/7325380#7325380

Comment: Sorry, I was just about to finish a solution with `DOMDocument` :)

Answer (score 3):

To scrap them properly you need `DOMDocument::loadHTML()`, `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`, `DomNode::attributes()`, `DOMNode::getNamedItem()` functions of DOMDOcument extension of PHP.