# Html - Extract information

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I need to extract some information from html code,
I have these two structures:

```
<p>Street 1a</p>
<p>12345 Berlin</p>
```

and

```
<p>
Street 1a
<br>
12345 Berlin
</p>
```

My question is how to extract the string 'Street 1a' from both structures with one method.

I thought about writing a method for every possible html-sturcure, but this is far to much work.
I also thought about parsing the whole html-code and do pattern matching but is also not very elegant,
like:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// Load the url's contents into the DOM
$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();

// pattern matching now
```

Anybody has some experience with this?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOMDocument for parsing HTML (instead of regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324620/domdocument-for-parsing-html-instead-of-regex)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="extract">
    <p>Street 1a</p>
    <p>12345 Berlin</p>
</div>
```

Your Script should like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#extract p').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
}); 
});
```