# PHP Dom Documents: getting textContent ignoring script tags and comments

Tags: php, xml, dom

i uses dom doc to load html from database like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($data);
$doc->encoding = 'utf-8';
$doc->saveHTML();
```

Then i get the body text by doing these:

```
$bodyNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("body");
$words = htmlspecialchars($bodyNodes->item(0)->textContent);
```

The words i've gotten included everything in the `<body>`. Things like `<scripts>` were also included.
How do i removed them and keep only the real text content?

Comment: you mean recursive extract text content of every element in `<body>` ?

Comment: yeap only text content which are meaningful, excluding javascripts or other html comments or etc which are not useful data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to visit all nodes and return their text. If some contain other node, visit them too.

This can be done with this basic recursive algorithm:

```
extractNode:
    if node is a text node or a cdata node, return its text
    if is an element node or a document node or a document fragment node:
        if it’s a script node, return an empty string
        return a concatenation of the result of calling extractNode on all the child nodes
    for everything else return nothing
```

Implementation:

```
function extractText($node) {    
    if (XML_TEXT_NODE === $node->nodeType || XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE === $node->nodeType) {
        return $node->nodeValue;
    } else if (XML_ELEMENT_NODE === $node->nodeType || XML_DOCUMENT_NODE === $node->nodeType || XML_DOCUMENT_FRAG_NODE === $node->nodeType) {
        if ('script' === $node->nodeName) return '';

        $text = '';
        foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
            $text .= extractText($childNode);
        }
        return $text;
    }
}
```

This will return the textContent of the given $node, ignoring script tags and comments.

```
$words = htmlspecialchars(extractText($bodyNodes->item(0)));
```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/CS3nMp7U

Comment: I've added a quick description of the algorithm

Answer (score 7):

You can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for this.

Borrowing the HTML arnaud used for his example above:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<p>
    test<span>foo<b>bar</b>
</p>
<script>
    ignored
</script>
<!-- comment is ignored -->
<p>test</p>
HTML;
```

You simply [query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) all [text nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Text-Nodes) that not are [not children of a script tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) and [do not evaluate to an empty string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space). You'll also make sure you dont [preserveWhiteSpace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace) so the whitespace used for formatting isnt considered.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$xp    = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('/html/body//text()[
    not(ancestor::script) and
    not(normalize-space(.) = "")
]');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    var_dump($node->textContent);
}
```

will output ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Uqpw9s))

```
string(10) "
    test"
string(3) "foo"
string(3) "bar"
string(4) "test"
```

Comment: This function helps. it's actually able to recognize and split sentence of words as one string.

Comment: @nuttynibbles it doesnt recognize words, nor sentences. XPath is a query language for XML. It has no clue about the content of an XML document, just about the structure. See [my answer here for an introduction to DOM concepts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)