# How to remove all ASCII codes from a string

Tags: php, character-encoding, ascii

My sentence include [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character codes like

```
&#x0022;&#x0023;&#x0024;&#x0025;
```

How can I remove all ASCII codes?

I tried `strip_tags()`, `html_entity_decode()`, and `htmlspecialchars()`, and they did not work.

Comment: If you remove these characters, aren't you going to loose the meaning of your sentence?

Comment: No, my sentences include japanese chars and normal chars. I need to remove japanese chars.

Comment: But those aren't Japanese characters, they are `"#$%`

Comment: This might help a little: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497885/remove-control-characters-from-php-string though it won't get the &#x; type html entity layout, you might be looking for a different preg_replace.

Comment: For things to work here you have to tell the exact problem, you can't say you have a problem with your dog, but in fact is your cat that got blind, but you are talking about your dog

Answer (score 2):

You could run this if you don't want the returning values:

```
preg_replace('/(&#x[0-9]{4};)/', '', $text);
```

But be warned. This is basically a nuker and with the way HTML entities work I am sure this will interfer with other parts of your string. I would recommend leaving them in personally and encoding them as @hakra shows.

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for preg_replace()

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to remove entities that resolve to non-ascii characters? If that is what you want you can use this code:

```
$str = '&#x0022; &#x0023; &#x0024; &#x0025; &#x7414;'; // " # $ % 琔
// decode entities
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// remove non-ascii characters
$str = preg_replace('/[^\x{0000}-\x{007F}]/u', '', $str);
```

Or

```
// decode only iso-8859-1 entities
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'iso-8859-1');
// remove any entities that remain
$str = preg_replace('/&#(x[0-9]{4}|\d+);/', '', $str);
```

If that's not what you want you need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the multibyte string extension at hand, this works:

```
$string = '&#x0022;&#x0023;&#x0024;&#x0025;';
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Which does give:

```
"#$%
```

Loosely related is:

- [PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters (☆)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11310258/367456)

---

With the DOM extension you could load it and convert it to a string which probably has the benefit to better deal with HTML elements and such:

```
echo simplexml_import_dom(@DomDocument::loadHTML('&#x0022;&#x0023;&#x0024;&#x0025;'))->xpath('//body/p')[0];
```

Which does output:

```
"#$%
```

If it contains HTML, you might need to export the inner html of that element which is explained in some other answer:

- [DOMDocument : how to get inner HTML as Strings separated by line-breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222453/domdocument-how-to-get-innerhtml)

Answer (score -1):

To remove Japanese characters from a string, you may use the following code:

```
// Decode the text to get correct UTF-8 text:
$text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

// Use the UTF-8 properties with `preg_replace` to remove all Japanese characters
$text = preg_replace('/\p{Katakana}|\p{Hiragana}|\p{Han}/u', '', $text);
```

**Documentation**:

[Unicode character properties](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)
[Unicode scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

> Some languages are composed of multiple scripts. There is no Japanese Unicode script. Instead, Unicode offers the Hiragana, Katakana, Han and Latin scripts that Japanese documents are usually composed of.

[Try the code here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gWkSSH)