# How to get "innerContent" with DOMdocument?

Tags: php, dom, innerxml

I need something like `InnerHTML` of a node, it is very simple, and perhaps I am not knowing how to use `childNodes`... I need some function that receives a node (DOMElement or DOMNode) with a root, and outputs the (DOM-XML object or XML-string value) filling. So, it is a "DOMnode node-root remover".

Example of workaround with PHP and regular expression:

```
 function xsl_getInner($ele) {
    // not works with $ele->childNodes
    $xml = $ele->ownerDocument->saveXML($ele);
    return preg_replace('/^<([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])\s?[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>$/s','$2',$xml);
 }
```

---

Related question: [How to change root of a node with DomDocument methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15646757/287948)

Comment: Which part(s) of [DOMDocument : how to get innerHTML()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222453/domdocument-how-to-get-innerhtml) or [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087103/367456) did not work for you?