# How to change root of a node with DOMDocument methods?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, appendchild, removechild

How to only change root's tag name of a DOM node?

In the DOM-Document model we can not change the property `documentElement` of a `DOMElement` object, so, we need "rebuild" the node... But how to "rebuild" with `childNodes` property?

---

NOTE: I can do this by [converting to string with saveXML and cuting root by regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15636739/287948)... But it is a workaround, not a DOM-solution.

---

## Tried but not works, PHP examples

PHP example (not works, but WHY?):

#### Try-1

```php
 // DOMElement::documentElement can not be changed, so... 

 function DomElement_renameRoot1($ele,$ROOTAG='newRoot') { 
    if (gettype($ele)=='object' && $ele->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $eaux = $doc->createElement($ROOTAG); // DOMElement

       foreach ($ele->childNodes as $node)  
       if ($node->nodeType == 1)  // DOMElement 
               $eaux->appendChild($node);  // error!
       elseif ($node->nodeType == 3)  // DOMText
               $eaux->appendChild($node); // error!
       return $eaux;
    } else
        die("ERROR: invalid DOM object as input");
  }
```

The `appendChild($node)` cause an error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' 
 with message 'Wrong Document Error'
```

#### Try-2

From @can suggestion (only pointing link) and my interpretation of the poor [dom-domdocument-renamenode manual](http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-renamenode.php).

```php
 function DomElement_renameRoot2($ele,$ROOTAG='newRoot') {
$ele->ownerDocument->renameNode($ele,null,"h1");
    return $ele;
 }
```

The renameNode() method caused an error,

```
Warning: DOMDocument::renameNode(): Not yet implemented
```

#### Try-3

From [PHP manual, comment 1](http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-renamenode.php).

```php
 function renameNode(DOMElement $node, $newName)
 {
     $newNode = $node->ownerDocument->createElement($newName);
     foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute)
        $newNode->setAttribute($attribute->nodeName, $attribute->nodeValue);
     while ($node->firstChild)
        $newNode->appendChild($node->firstChild); // changes firstChild to next!?
     $node->ownerDocument->replaceChild($newNode, $node); // changes $node?
     // not need return $newNode; 
 }
```

The replaceChild() method caused an error,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'
```

Comment: I added an answer that shows a function how to do it and also lightly points out where the error is in the code in your question. A larger example is on a different answer I linked in there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16315039/367456

Comment: The root tag is commonly expected to be the document element or root node. So the wording you use in your question might be a little misleading. Do you want to rename the tagname of the root element of the document or do you just want to rename a domelements tagname? (Clarification question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this has not been really answered yet, the error you get about not found is because of a little error in the `renameNode()` function you've copied.

In [a somewhat related question about renaming different elements in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307103/use-domdocument-to-replace-all-header-tags-with-the-h4-tags) I've seen this problem as well and [used an adoption of that function in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16314814/367456) that does not have this error:

```
/**
 * Renames a node in a DOM Document.
 *
 * @param DOMElement $node
 * @param string     $name
 *
 * @return DOMNode
 */
function dom_rename_element(DOMElement $node, $name) {
    $renamed = $node->ownerDocument->createElement($name);

    foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
        $renamed->setAttribute($attribute->nodeName, $attribute->nodeValue);
    }

    while ($node->firstChild) {
        $renamed->appendChild($node->firstChild);
    }

    return $node->parentNode->replaceChild($renamed, $node);
}
```

You might have spotted it in the last line of the function body: This is using `->parentNode` instead of `->ownerDocument`. As `$node` was not a child of the document, you did get the error. And it also was wrong to assume that it should be. Instead use the parent element to search for the child in there to replace it ;)

This has not been outlined in the PHP manual usernotes so far, however, if you did follow the link to the blog-post that originally suggested the `renameNode()` function you could find a comment below it offering this solution as well.

Anyway, my variant here uses a slightly different variable naming and is more distinct about the types. Like the example in the PHP manual it misses the variant that deals with namespace nodes. I'm not yet booked what would be best, e.g. creating an additional function dealing with it, taking over namespace from the node to rename or changing the namespace explicitly in a different function.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to understand that the `DOMDocument` is only the hierarchical root of the document-tree. It's name is always `#document`. You want to rename the root-element, which is the `$document->documentElement`.

If you want to copy nodes form a document to another document, you'll need to use the [importNode()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) function: `$document->importNode($nodeInAnotherDocument)`

**Edit:**

`renameNode()` is not implemented yet, so you should make another root, and simply replace it with the old one. If you use `DOMDocument->createElement()` you don't need to use `importNode()` on it later.

```
$oldRoot = $doc->documentElement;
$newRoot = $doc->createElement('new-root');

foreach ($oldRoot->attributes as $attr) {
  $newRoot->setAttribute($attr->nodeName, $attr->nodeValue);
}

while ($oldRoot->firstChild) {
  $newRoot->appendChild($oldRoot->firstChild);
}

$doc->replaceChild($newRoot, $oldRoot);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot by the clue, and perhaps a solution (!), but I not see yet  how `DOMDocument::importNode()` can be used in my [xml_renameNode()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702279/287948) function, without a loop, if something like  `importNode($node->childNodes)` can not be used.

Comment: These are two different solutions: if you want to rename the root tag's name you should use `$document->documentElement->renameNode()`; if you want to make another document with another root, use `$document->importNode`.

Comment: Yes, good practice... And, well, now I understand the context where you and @PointedEars see  `importNode` as a solution to the rename problem... But even when is "another document with another root" you need a loop.

Comment: About your edit: thanks, but it is exactly the [same algorithm than the mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702279/287948), with same loop. The difference is that in a function scope I not need replaceChild.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't thorws a DOMException, so it works. The concept is you need to change the documentElement, not the document itself. And: you cannot make it without the loops, until `renameNode()` is not implemented.

Comment: This does not consider namespaces and nodes that are not root element nodes.

Comment: It's unFUCKAbelievable that one has to do SO MUCH WORK to simply ASSERT CONTROL of how the root element is named.

Answer (score 1):

This is an variation of my "Try-3" (see question), and **works fine**!

```php
  function xml_renameNode(DOMElement $node, $newName, $cpAttr=true) {
      $newNode = $node->ownerDocument->createElement($newName);
      if ($cpAttr && is_array($cpAttr)) {
        foreach ($cpAttr as $k=>$v)
             $newNode->setAttribute($k, $v);
      } elseif ($cpAttr)
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute)
             $newNode->setAttribute($attribute->nodeName, $attribute->nodeValue);

      while ($node->firstChild)
          $newNode->appendChild($node->firstChild);
      return $newNode;
  }
```

Of course, if you show how to use [DOMDocument::renameNode](http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-renamenode.php) (without errors!), the *bounty* goes for you!

Comment: You have been mislead, and are referring to bogus documentation. [`DOMDocument::renameNode()` as of DOM Level 3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Document3-renameNode) is [not implemented in PHP as of yet](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), so any approach using that must fail (or would at least be unreliable as it would be only in trunk builds).  However, you do not need `DOMDocument::renameNode()`.  [DOM Level 2 Core methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-785887307) suffice here, see my answer.

Comment: I used the renameNode-link pointed by Kan's answer, that showed us a valid solution before before Methai edit my question with the PHP-tag.
After the Methai's scope reduction, @kan show that [PHP have a 2-yers-old bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51389). No DOM Level 2 Core methods is suffice (!), only using a loop. A loop-solution is first showed here by me.

Comment: You and @pozs not show an alternative solution for this one, using appendChild in a loop.

Comment: @kan has showed that they have no clue what they are talking about, and you fell for the troll. It's _not_ a bug that renameNode() is not implemented in PHP as of yet. You could call it an oversight, perhaps, considering that `textContent` from DOM Level 3 is implemented as `DOMNode::textContent`. Your "solution" is not only overly complicated, it is _not_ a proper implementation of `DOMDocument::renameNode()`. I have given you hints as how to implement `DOMDocument::renameNode()` properly already, and you let the bounty expire. ISTM you are much too sure of yourself for your own good.

Comment: +1, I think it's a good shot even if not the 'proper' way. @PointedEars You're being a little harsh in a lot of the comments on here, just not needed.

Answer (score 1):

ISTM in your approach you attempt to *import nodes* from *another* `DOMDocument`, so you need to use the [`importNode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) method:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();

/* Make a `foo` element the root element of $d */
$root = $d->createElement("foo");
$d->appendChild($root);

/* Append a `bar` element as the child element of the root of $d */
$child = $d->createElement("bar");
$root->appendChild($child);

/* New document */
$d2 = new DOMDocument();

/* Make a `baz` element the root element of $d2 */
$root2 = $d2->createElement("baz");
$d2->appendChild($root2);

/* 
 * Import a clone of $child (from $d) into $d2,
 * with its child nodes imported recursively
 */
$child2 = $d2->importNode($child, true);

/* Add the clone as the child node of the root of $d2 */
$root2->appendChild($child2);
```

However, it is far easier to append the child nodes to a new parent element (thereby moving them), and replace the old root with that parent element:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();

/* Make a `foo` element the root element of $d */
$root = $d->createElement("foo");
$d->appendChild($root);

/* Append a `bar` element as the child element of the root of $d */
$child = $d->createElement("bar");
$root->appendChild($child);

/* <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <foo><bar/></foo> */
echo $d->saveXML();

$root2 = $d->createElement("baz");

/* Make the `bar` element the child element of `baz` */
$root2->appendChild($child);

/* Replace `foo` with `baz` */
$d->replaceChild($root2, $root);

/* <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <baz><bar/></baz> */
echo $d->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you show new clues and possible solution! Can you show in terms of a xml_renameNode() function? My problem is to undertand how to do `$root->appendChild($child)` if child is a list of nodes... Se my "while ($node->firstChild)" implementation. You can do (with replaceChild) without the loop?

Comment: I do not think you can append several children without calling `appendChild()` in a loop (my client-side script library contains an `appendChildren()` method do just that). As for a `renameNode()` implementation in PHP, you just need to instantiate a subclass of `DOMDocument`. (Too bad you let the bounty expire.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not missing anything but I happened to have the similar problem and was able to solve it by using use `DomDocument::replaceChild(...)`.

```
   /* @var $doc DOMDocument */
   $doc = DOMImplementation::createDocument(NULL, 'oldRoot');

   /* @var $newRoot DomElement */
   $newRoot = $doc->createElement('newRoot');
   /* all the code to create the elements under $newRoot */

   $doc->replaceChild($newRoot, $doc->documentElement);

   $doc->documentElement->isSameNode($newRoot) === true;
```

What threw me off initially was that `$doc->documentElement` was readonly, but the above worked and seems to be much simpler solution IF the `$newRoot` was created with the same `DomDocument`, otherwise you'll need do the `importNode` solution as described above.  From your question is appears that `$newRoot` could be created from the same `$doc`.

Let us know if this worked out for you. Cheers.

EDIT: Noticed in version 20031129 that the `DomDocument::$formatOutput`, if set, does not format `$newRoot` output when you finally call `$doc->saveXML()`