# Replace HTML tags with DOMdocument while keeping nested tags

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I have a complex HTML structure but a part of it looks like this

```
....
<div class="otherclass"> 
   <div class="myclass">
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="myclass">
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </div>
</div>
...
```

I would like to transform it into

```
...
<div class="otherclass">
   <span>
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </span>
   <span>
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </span>
</div>
...
```

What I currently have is

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*/div[@class='myclass']");
foreach( $elements as $element) {

    $new = $doc->createElement('span', $element->nodeValue);
    $parent = $element->parentNode;
    $parent->removeChild($element);
    $parent->appendChild($new);

}
```

But this will strip all HTML inside:

```
...
<div class="otherclass">
   <span>some HTML...</span>
   <span>some HTML...</span>
</div>
...
```

I have the HTML as string as well

Comment: You want to rename a tag/element with DOMDocument. Perhaps search for that? Maybe you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16314814/367456 ? (I searched and this turned up in google #1, but I also remembered from mind that there was  something related earlier)