# Appending an Element multiple times in DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

Is there a way to use repeated child elements in DOMDOCUMENT in PHP?  In my case, the Billing and Shipping information will always be the same.  For example:

```
$fullname = "John Doe";
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml_billing = $xml->createElement("Billing");
$xml_shipping = $xml->createElement("Shipping");
$xml_fullname = $xml->createElement("FullName");
$xml_fullname->nodeValue = $fullname;
$xml_billing->appendChild($xml_fullname);
$xml_shipping->appendChild($xml_fullname);
```

However, in this case, it removes the element from Billing and leaves it only in Shipping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might not be obvious for you, but if you append *the same* element to another parent it is moved around in a `DOMDocument`.

You can prevent that easily by using the created FullName element as a prototype and clone it for the append operation:

```
$xml_billing->appendChild(clone $xml_fullname);
$xml_shipping->appendChild(clone $xml_fullname);
```

This then does what you were trying to achieve if I read your question right.

---

And another hint as I just see it: The following two lines:

```
$xml_fullname = $xml->createElement("FullName");
$xml_fullname->nodeValue = $fullname;
```

You can write as one:

```
$xml_fullname = $xml->createElement("FullName", $fullname);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ((another question, leveraging the context)) The use of `clone` is equivalent to importNode, `$xml_billing->appendChild( $xml_billing->ownerDocument->importNode(  $xml_fullname) )`? Or there are some difference?

Comment: Thank you hakre for the clarification!

Comment: @PeterKrauss: Good question. I don't think so because `importNode()` does allow to take a node from a *different* document whereas in this example clone is used on an element from the *same* document.