# Simple HTML DOM Parser PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to select a particular part of a html page using '[Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)'.

My code so far works but it returns the **complete** text which is great, but I only want to display the single `P BARCODE[pb]` line.

My (working) PHP code is as follows;

```
$homepage = file_get_html('http://example.com/SomeTextPage');

foreach($homepage->find('text') as $element) 
       echo $element->innertext . '<br>'; // line 29
```

This returns the following on my page (this is the view source display);

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
EXP DATE[p43]=12-31-97<BR>
PCODE1[p44]=-<BR>
PCODE2[p45]=-<BR>
PCODE3[p46]=0<BR>
P TYPE[p47]=1<BR>
TOT CHKOUT[p48]=56<BR>
TOT RENWAL[p49]=17<BR>
CUR CHKOUT[p50]=3<BR>
HOME LIBR[p53]=0000<BR>
PMESSAGE[p54]=<BR>
MBLOCK[p56]=-<BR>
REC TYPE[p80]=p<BR>
RECORD #[p81]=110220<BR>
REC LENG[p82]=1126<BR>
CREATED[p83]=01-09-97<BR>
UPDATED[p84]=06-05-97<BR>
REVISIONS[p85]=139<BR>
AGENCY[p86]=1<BR>
CL RTRND[p95]=0<BR>
MONEY OWED[p96]=$1.35<BR>
BLK UNTIL[p101]=  -  -  <BR>
CUR ITEMA[p102]=0<BR>
CUR ITEMB[p103]=0<BR>
PIUSE[p104]=0<BR>
OD PENALTY[p105]=0<BR>
ILL CHKOUT[p122]=3<BR>
PATRN NAME[pn]=Jackson, Richard<BR>
ADDRESS[pa]=322 San Diego St<BR>
ADDRESS2[ph]=El Cerrito, CA 99999<BR>
TELEPHONE[pt]=510-555-1212<BR>
UNIV ID[pu]=111111111<BR>
P BARCODE[pb]=21913000482538<BR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I suppose I need to select the 32nd `<br>` line or more importantly the `[P BARCODE[pb]]` line - is this possible?

The `[P BARCODE[pb]]` line isn't always the 32nd line, but the `[P BARCODE[pb]]` text never changes.

Perhaps I am approaching this the wrong way?

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I would try `$homepage->find('text')[31]`, or is that too easy?

Comment: is it line no 32nd fixed

Comment: @MrLister that doesn't work. I get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\... on line 29`. Line 29 is my echo

Comment: @Irfan that's a good point, no it sometimes changes between line 31 and 32. The text `[P BARCODE[pb]` never changes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to try to use regexp?

```
$subject = 'P BARCODE[pb]=21913000482538<BR>';
$pattern = '/P\sBARCODE\[pb\]=([0-9]*)<BR>/'; 
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that, wrap every line of text in a `<span>` so you can access them individually.

Apperantly there is another option, I'd like to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222754/5374294) answer

Comment: Thanks but I don't have access to the external URL in order to format the text into `<span>` tags

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $element->innertext;
$array = explode('<br>', $var);
echo $array[31];
```

Comment: Thanks @Irfan but that doesn't work. I get `Notice: Undefined offset: 31 in C:\xampp... on line 32`. Line 32 being `echo $array[31];`. a var_dump of $array shows `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) " " [1]=> string(0) "" }`