# I want php code to find href title and some other infos from html table

Tags: php, html, html-table, domdocument

I create this code until now:

```
<?php
$url=" SOME HTML URL ";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('href');
}
?>
```

I have html pages with tables so i want the link the title and the date. Example of html code:

```
<TR>
    <TD align="center" vAlign="top" bgColor="#ffffff" class="smalltext">3</TD>
    <TD  class="plaintext" ><a href="pdf/blahblah.pdf" target="_blank" class="link1style">THIS IS THE TITLE</a> </TD>
    <TD  align="center" class="plaintext" >THIS IS DATE</TD>
</TR>
```

It works fine for me for the link, but i don't know how to take the others.

Tnx.

Comment: *(related)* [Noob Question about DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)

Comment: (related) http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

Where you are doing this:

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

You are getting back all the A tags. There only happens to be one.

If you want to get the text "THIS IS DATE", you're aren't going to get it by looking in A tags because the text is not inside an A tag - it is in a TD tag.

```
$tds = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

... would work to get all the TD elements, or you could assign an ID to the element you want to target and use `getElementById` instead.

Basically, though, this information is all in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), which you absolutely **should read before asking questions**. Happy reading!

Once again, that's: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php